# How can I overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?

Tags: python, json

I have a basic dict as follows:

```py
sample = {}
sample['title'] = "String"
sample['somedate'] = somedatetimehere
```

When I try to do `jsonify(sample)` I get:

> TypeError: datetime.datetime(2012, 8, 8, 21, 46, 24, 862000) is not JSON serializable

What can I do such that my dictionary sample can overcome the error above?

**Note:** Though it may not be relevant, the dictionaries are generated from the retrieval of records out of `mongodb` where when I print out `str(sample['somedate'])`, the output is `2012-08-08 21:46:24.862000`.

Comment: Is this specifically python in general, or possibly django?

Comment: It technically is specifically python, I am not using django, but retrieving records out of mongodb.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON datetime between Python and JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript)

Comment: I am using mongoengine, but if pymongo has better ways of getting around this or overcoming this, please tell.

Comment: @jdi That answer you linked to as duplicate appears to makes no sense to me. If you can post an answer here that would make sense in my context, that would be more helpful.

Comment: That duplicate I posted is the generic way to handle this where you specify the extra parameter to `JSON` as a handler. I have posted a pymongo specific answer.

Comment: The linked question is essentially telling you not to try to serialize the datetime object, but rather to convert it to a string in the common ISO format before serializing.

Comment: For a generic solution that handles more that just `datetime.datetime`, see [**_Making object JSON serializable with regular encoder_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478287/making-object-json-serializable-with-regular-encoder).

Comment: cannot import name json_util

Comment: If you have the option to store the datetime as a float (seconds since epoch, as from `time.time()`) that is portable and you can call `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` when you need a python `datetime`.

Answer (score 554, accepted):

## Updated for 2018

The original answer accommodated the way MongoDB "date" fields were represented as:

`{"$date": 1506816000000}`

If you want a generic Python solution for serializing `datetime` to json, check out [@jjmontes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36142844/293064) for a quick solution which requires no dependencies.

---

As you are using mongoengine (per comments) and pymongo is a dependency, pymongo has built-in utilities to help with json serialization:
http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.10.1/api/bson/json_util.html

Example usage (serialization):

```
from bson import json_util
import json

json.dumps(anObject, default=json_util.default)
```

Example usage (deserialization):

```
json.loads(aJsonString, object_hook=json_util.object_hook)
```

---

### Django

Django provides a native `DjangoJSONEncoder` serializer that deals with this kind of properly.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

return json.dumps(
  item,
  sort_keys=True,
  indent=1,
  cls=DjangoJSONEncoder
)
```

One difference I've noticed between `DjangoJSONEncoder` and using a custom `default` like this:

```
import datetime
import json

def default(o):
    if isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime)):
        return o.isoformat()

return json.dumps(
  item,
  sort_keys=True,
  indent=1,
  default=default
)
```

Is that Django strips a bit of the data:

```
 "last_login": "2018-08-03T10:51:42.990", # DjangoJSONEncoder 
 "last_login": "2018-08-03T10:51:42.990239", # default
```

So, you may need to be careful about that in some cases.

Comment: Is it good/bad practice to be mixing multiple libraries i.e. having mongoengine for inserting docs and pymongo for query/retrieval?

Comment: Its not bad practice, it just implies some dependency on the libraries that your main library uses. If you can't accomplish what you need from mongoengine, then you drop down to pymongo. Its the same with `Django MongoDB`. With the later, you would try to stay within the django ORM to maintain backend agnostic state. But sometimes you can't do what you need in the abstraction, so you drop down a layer. In this case, its completely unrelated to your problem since you are just using utility methods to accompany the JSON format.

Comment: I am trying this out with Flask and it appears that by using json.dump, I am unable to put a jsonify() wrapper around it such that it returns in application/json. Attempting to do return jsonify(json.dumps(sample, default=json_util.default))

Comment: I am assuming `jsonify` would try and serialize it again. Is it a flask function specifically?

Comment: I think it is a flask function specifically to get it to return of "content-type: application/json" that usually accepts a dict, but I get: "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required". I hope django is not better for this sort of thing...

Comment: You would just need to use the `flask` general response object and set the content-type

Comment: @amit Its not so much about memorizing syntax, as it is about getting good at reading documentation and storing enough info in my head to recognise where and when I need to retrieve it again. In this case, one might say "Oh a custom object with json" and then quickly refresh on that usage

Comment: I had been using this method `bson.json_util.dumps(anObject)`, but your example method `json.dumps(anObject, default=bson.json_util.default)` is exponentially faster. Thank you!

Comment: This will convert datetime to a dict with $date, not I wanted: `json.dumps({'d':d}, default=json_util.default)`  -> `'{"d": {"$date": 1506816000000}}'`

Comment: @guyskk I haven't tracked changes in bjson or mongo since I wrote this 5 years ago. But if you want control over the serialisation of the datetime then you need to write your own default handler function as illustrated in the answer given by  jgbarah

Comment: The answer by jgbarah doesn't have any example for the object_hook, and the bjson source code doesn't show any sign of `json_util` or `object_hook`, 5 years ago or today. Can anyone point me to an example? I fundamentally don't know input/return structure is expected except for just guessing and checking.

Comment: @AlanSE the bson module is being provided by pymongo, so you can see the source here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/master/bson/json_util.py

Comment: in the personal don't like use external librarys, i prefer the utisl from python as example datetime, isoformat()..etc..

Comment: @DiegoAvila sure under normal circumstances it is wise to always evaluate your dependencies. But in this case the question was about the Python mongodb client which comes with the needed serialisation facilities.

Comment: Also in Django, if you have this problem with model serialization in a JSONField (from django.contrib.postgres.fields), the solution is to add encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder. ie: my_field = JSONField(... encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder)

Comment: The question is not tagged as either Mongo or Django...but low and behold.

Comment: @aaa90210 yea thought the immediate questions that followed in the comments clarified that it was a mongodb and Django situation

Comment: When I am using json.loads(aJsonString, object_hook=json_util.object_hook) I am getting Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable

Comment: @NilaySingh that sounds similar to this other question that I answered. Might want to check your json string format and make sure it uses "$oid" and not "ObjectId()" in the string form: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409539/496445

Comment: @jdi I have a complex json object with a timedelta format and it is only working with `DjangoJSONEncoder` I am not sure if I can any other default ways or not. What do you think?

Answer (score 1711):

My quick & dirty JSON dump that eats dates and everything:

```
json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
```

> `default` is a function applied to objects that aren't serializable.
> In this case it's `str`, so it just converts everything it doesn't know to strings. Which is great for serialization but not so great when deserializing (hence the "quick & dirty") as anything might have been string-ified without warning, e.g. a function or numpy array.

Comment: This is awesome, But unfortunately I did not understand what happened?
Can anyone explain this answer?

Comment: @KishorPawar: `default` is a function applied to objects that aren't serializable. In this case it's `str`, so it just converts everything it doesn't know to strings. Which is great for serialization but not so great when deserializing (hence the "quick & dirty") as anything might have been string-ified without warning, e.g. a function or numpy array.

Comment: @Mark awesome. Thanks. Useful when you know type of those non-serializable values like dates.

Comment: Can someone share how to return back to original dictionary?

Comment: repr might have a slight advantage over str, but of course there are no guarantees.

Comment: @jjmontes, doesn't work for everything, eg `json.dumps({():1,type(None):2},default=str)` raises `TypeError`, can't have type or tuple.

Comment: @c-urchin, `repr` has same issues as `str` for examples in above comment.

Comment: I am sorry after this comment only i found that its syntax mistake and not of `default=str`.  Thank you for this

Comment: Had to wrap mine in `print(...)` to get it to pretty print.

Comment: This saved a year of my life. I would be cautious to use the indent when sending data over APIs

Comment: This works :-), but when testing to use this also for serialisable data and writing the resulting string to file using `json.dump()`, I find that my whole data set is enclosed in double quotes, and the double quotes around the separate elements are (then logically) escaped.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @DannyBullis json has pprint built-in:   json.dumps(x, default=str, indent=4)

Comment: @Mark `"but not so great when deserializing"` - it returns a standartized parseable string. Do you know better human-readable json compatible representation?

Comment: @SmitJohnth I'm glad you ask, because this is why I made json-tricks: https://github.com/mverleg/pyjson_tricks

Comment: man, this should be the default in Python

Comment: Django users: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

Comment: I have to wonder why default does not default to str in the first place.

Answer (score 625):

Building on other answers, a simple solution based on a specific serializer that just converts `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date` objects to strings.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        return obj.isoformat()
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))
```

As seen, the code just checks to find out if object is of class `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date`, and then uses `.isoformat()` to produce a serialized version of it, according to ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS (which is easily decoded by JavaScript). If more complex serialized representations are sought, other code could be used instead of str() (see other answers to this question for examples). The code ends by raising an exception, to deal with the case it is called with a non-serializable type.

This json_serial function can be used as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
from json import dumps

print dumps(datetime.now(), default=json_serial)
```

The details about how the default parameter to json.dumps works can be found in [Section Basic Usage of the json module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage).

Comment: yeah the correct answer, more pretty import datetime
and if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime) , I lost many time because don't used from datetime import datetime , anyway thanks

Comment: but this does not explain how to deserialise it with the correct type, isnt it ?

Comment: No, @BlueTrin , nothing said about that. In my case, I'm deserializing in JavaScript, which works out of the box.

Comment: This will cause unexpected behavior if the json module ever updates to include serialization of datetime objects.

Comment: I'm worried that the error messages this replaces will be less helpful, and that it woudln't work on non-datatime values at all. I don't fully understand the api this working with. All I expect is that you'd have to call the base class in the default case like http://stackoverflow.com/a/27058505/1695680 does.

Comment: Keep in mind that `obj.isoformat()` (and `str(obj)`) will output the timezone info (like `-08:00`), so if the same date was defined in different time zones their json representations won't match. The solution would be to convert dates to either UTC or timestamps.

Comment: "If specified, default should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object or raise a TypeError. If not specified, TypeError is raised." Thanks.

Comment: @serg But converting times to UTC would unify `01:00:00+01:00` and `02:00:00+00:00` which are not supposed to be the same, depending on context.  They refer to the same point in time of course, but the offset might be a relevant aspect of the value.

Comment: +1 for supporting `datetime.date`. However, maybe even better idea would be to use duck typing instead of isinstance, to support all `obj` that implements `isoformat()` method (e.g. pendulum and arrow)?

Comment: How would you do that in a nested dictionary that somewhere has datetime?

Comment: Do you lose any information from the datetime that doesn't get into the isoformat string?

Answer (score 296):

I have just encountered this problem and my solution is to subclass `json.JSONEncoder`:

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, datetime):
            return o.isoformat()

        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
```

In your call do something like: `json.dumps(yourobj, cls=DateTimeEncoder)` The `.isoformat()` I got from one of the answers above.

Comment: upped because implementing a custom JSONEncoder should be the proper way to go

Comment: Not only should this be the top answer, this should be part of the regular json encoder. If only decoding was less ambiguous..

Comment: this worked perfectly for encoding python boto3 aws responses.

Comment: if i did `json.dumps(cursor.fetchone(), cls=DateTimeEncoder)` it will double encode my data which will result `/"` escape - anyway to solve this?

Comment: For those using Django, see `DjangoJSONEncoder`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

Comment: Super helpful. Last line could be `return super(DateTimeEncoder, self).default(o)`

Comment: With Python 3 the last line is even simpler: ``return super().default(o)``

Comment: @S.Kirby Your comment needs to be an answer

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Well, jdi's accepted answer includes `DjangoJSONEncoder` now. But admittedly, it didn't when I posted my comment.

Comment: It would be good to add the decoder code to your example as well

Comment: Worked fine, but I have to add parameter "date" to isinstance.

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon I used this answer for Pendulum DateTimes in Peewee ORM. You'll find a deserializer example here: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/2487#issuecomment-969256688

Answer (score 146):

Convert the date to a string

```
sample['somedate'] = str( datetime.utcnow() )
```

Comment: And how could I deserialize it in Python?

Comment: The problem is if you have many datetime objects embedded deeply in a data structure, or they are random. This isn't a reliable method.

Comment: to deserialize: `oDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(sDate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')`.  Formats obtained from:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Downvoted as it ignores timezone information. Keep in mind that `.now()` uses local time, without indicating this. At least `.utcnow()` should be used (and then a +0000 or Z appended)

Comment: @DanielF `At least .utcnow() should be used` Not exactly, `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` is recommended, see warning in: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow.

Answer (score 85):

For others who do not need or want to use the pymongo library for this, you can achieve datetime JSON conversion easily with this small snippet:

```
def default(obj):
    """Default JSON serializer."""
    import calendar, datetime

    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        if obj.utcoffset() is not None:
            obj = obj - obj.utcoffset()
        millis = int(
            calendar.timegm(obj.timetuple()) * 1000 +
            obj.microsecond / 1000
        )
        return millis
    raise TypeError('Not sure how to serialize %s' % (obj,))
```

Then use it like so:

```
import datetime, json
print json.dumps(datetime.datetime.now(), default=default)
```

Output:

```
'1365091796124'
```

Comment: Shouldn't `millis=` be indented inside the if statement? It's also probably better to use str(obj) to get the ISO format which I would think is more common.

Comment: Why would you want it to be indented?  This snippet works and the resulting output can easily be deserialized/parsed from javascript.

Comment: Because obj may not be a [time, date, datetime] object

Comment: your example is incorrect if the local timezone has non-zero UTC offset (most of them). `datetime.now()` returns local time (as a naive datetime object) but your code assumes that `obj` is in UTC if it is not timezone-aware. Use `datetime.utcnow()` instead.

Comment: Adjusted it to raise a type error if obj is unrecognized as per the Python documentation recommendation at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#basic-usage.

Answer (score 71):

Here is my solution:

```
import json

class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        try:
            return super().default(obj)
        except TypeError:
            return str(obj)
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
json.dumps(dictionary, cls=DatetimeEncoder)
```

Comment: agree.  Much better, at least out of the mongodb context.  You can do `isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime)` within the TypeError, add more types to handle, and finish up with the `str(obj)` or `repr(obj)`.  And all your dumps can just point to this specialized class.

Comment: @Natim this solution is the best. +1

Comment: What about decoding?

Comment: @ThomasSauvajon https://stackoverflow.com/a/40489783/186202

Answer (score 65):

If you are using Python 3.7, then the best solution is using
[`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat) and
[`datetime.fromisoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat); they work with both naive and
aware `datetime` objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone
from datetime import timedelta
import json

def default(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        return { '_isoformat': obj.isoformat() }
    raise TypeError('...')

def object_hook(obj):
    _isoformat = obj.get('_isoformat')
    if _isoformat is not None:
        return datetime.fromisoformat(_isoformat)
    return obj

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #d = { 'now': datetime(2000, 1, 1) }
    d = { 'now': datetime(2000, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=-8))) }
    s = json.dumps(d, default=default)
    print(s)
    print(d == json.loads(s, object_hook=object_hook))
```

output:

```
{"now": {"_isoformat": "2000-01-01T00:00:00-08:00"}}
True
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or below, and you only care about the time value (not
the timezone), then you can use `datetime.timestamp()` and
`datetime.fromtimestamp()` instead;

If you are using Python 3.6 or below, and you do care about the timezone, then
you can get it via `datetime.tzinfo`, but you have to serialize this field
by yourself; the easiest way to do this is to add another field `_tzinfo` in the
serialized object;

Finally, beware of precisions in all these examples;

Comment: datetime.isoformat() is also present in Python 2.7: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Comment: Very helpful solution. Could it also support `datetime.time`?

Comment: @idbrii As @egvo said, you forgot `default=default` in your edit, which introduced the error. But you are right `super().default(obj)` is useless here. In fact, it came from a json-encoder example where it is useful.

Comment: this is my favorite answer, since it a) includes deserialization and b) is very simple/easy to understand

Answer (score 36):

You should apply the `.strftime()` method on a `datetime.datetime` object to make it a `string`.

Here's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

time_dict = {'time': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')}
sample_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
sample_dict.update(time_dict)
sample_dict
```

Output:

```
Out[0]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'time': '2017-10-31T15:16:30'}
```

---

[UPDATE]:

In Python 3.6 or later, you can simply use the `.isoformat()` method:

```py
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now().isoformat()
```

Comment: how to encode this ?

Comment: "Update" or similar [does not belong in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011) (near *"Changelogs"*). There is a full revision history on this platform. The answer should be as if it was ***written right now***.

Comment: @PeterMortensen why do you add some wrong information to the answer?! `isoformat()` exists in python3.6 not just version 3.7 onwards. I think you've confused it with `fromisoformat()` instead. BTW, I know about the history of posts, but I usually do that to indicate that this part of the answer is newer to a reader for better attention.

Comment: @BikashCocboy what do you mean by encode? you mean convert it back from string to datetime? if so you can simply use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2017-10-31T15:16:30')`

Answer (score 29):

The json.dumps method can accept an optional parameter called *default* which is expected to be a function. Every time JSON tries to convert a value it does not know how to convert, it will call the function we passed to it. The function will receive the object in question, and it is expected to return the JSON representation of the object.

```
def myconverter(o):
  if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
    return o.__str__()

print(json.dumps(d, default = myconverter))
```

Comment: Love this, it's very compact. However, I'm using `o.isoformat()`.

Comment: This feature should be more widely used!

Answer (score 22):

I have an application with a similar issue; my approach was to JSONize the datetime value as a 6-item list (year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds); you could go to microseconds as a 7-item list, but I had no need to:

```
class DateTimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            encoded_object = list(obj.timetuple())[0:6]
        else:
            encoded_object =json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
        return encoded_object

sample = {}
sample['title'] = "String"
sample['somedate'] = datetime.datetime.now()

print sample
print json.dumps(sample, cls=DateTimeEncoder)
```

produces:

```
{'somedate': datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 1, 16, 22, 45, 890000), 'title': 'String'}
{"somedate": [2013, 8, 1, 16, 22, 45], "title": "String"}
```

Comment: Fails to work if the time saved is saved by doing datetime.utcnow()

Comment: What error are you seeing with datetime.utcnow()?  It works okay for me.

Answer (score 21):

My solution (with less verbosity, I think):

```
def default(o):
    if type(o) is datetime.date or type(o) is datetime.datetime:
        return o.isoformat()

def jsondumps(o):
    return json.dumps(o, default=default)
```

Then use `jsondumps` instead of `json.dumps`. It will print:

```
>>> jsondumps({'today': datetime.date.today()})
'{"today": "2013-07-30"}'
```

I you want, later you can add other special cases to this with a simple twist of the `default` method. Example:

```
def default(o):
    if type(o) is datetime.date or type(o) is datetime.datetime:
        return o.isoformat()
    if type(o) is decimal.Decimal:
        return float(o)
```

Comment: You should use isinstance(o, (datetime.date, datetime.datetime,)). Probably wouldn't hurt to include datetime.time too.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution anymore. Probably the conversions should take a more privileged place -- and also a more understandable place -- in your code, so you know what you are converting to when you put things into a database, or whatever, instead of having everything being done by a transparent function. But I don't know.

Comment: JSON is good for serialising data for processing later. You may not know exactly what that data is. And you shouldn't need to. Serialising JSON should just work. Just like converting unicode to ascii should. Python's inability to do this without obscure functions makes it annoying to use. Database validation is a separate issue IMO.

Comment: No, it shouldn't "just work". If you don't know how the serialization occurred and has to access the data later from another program/language, then you're lost.

Comment: JSON is commonly used for strings, ints, floats, dates (I'm sure others use currency, temperatures, commonly too). But datetime is part of the standard library and should support de/serialisation. If it wasn't for this question, I'd still be manually searching my incredibly complex json blobs (which I didn't always create the structure for) for dates and serialising them 1 by 1.

Comment: @AdamGriffiths: what should the serialized value be? How do you serialize `datetime(2014, 10, 13, 19, 31, 0, 123456, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)` without losing info? `.timestamp()` -- `1413243060.123456` is efficient and easy to parse but the original UTC offset is lost, `.isoformat()` -- `2014-10-13T19:31:00.123456-04:00` is better but it loses zoneinfo (UTC offset along is ambiguous if you want to do date arithmetic, or would you combine them: `{'rfc3339': '2014-10-13T19:31:00.123456-04:00', 'timezone': 'America/New_York', 'timestamp': 1413243060.123456}`?

Comment: Point taken. Dates are messy. I'm starting to agree with @fiatjaf, but I still believe part of the problem lies in the python standard library.

Answer (score 20):

This question repeats time and time again—a simple way to patch the *json* module such that serialization would support *datetime*.

```
import json
import datetime

json.JSONEncoder.default = lambda self,obj: (obj.isoformat() if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime) else None)
```

Then use JSON serialization as you always do, this time with datetime being serialized as *isoformat*.

```
json.dumps({'created':datetime.datetime.now()})
```

Resulting in: '{"created": "2015-08-26T14:21:31.853855"}'

See more details and some words of caution at:
[Stack Overflow: JSON datetime between Python and JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455580/json-datetime-between-python-and-javascript/32224522#32224522)

Comment: Monkey patch FTW. The nasty thing is of course that this modifies the behaviour of the json module in your whole application, which may surprise others in a large application, so should generally be used with care imho.

Answer (score 11):

You have to supply a custom encoder class with the `cls` parameter of `json.dumps`. To quote from [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html):

```
>>> import json
>>> class ComplexEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, obj):
...         if isinstance(obj, complex):
...             return [obj.real, obj.imag]
...         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
...
>>> dumps(2 + 1j, cls=ComplexEncoder)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
>>> ComplexEncoder().encode(2 + 1j)
'[2.0, 1.0]'
>>> list(ComplexEncoder().iterencode(2 + 1j))
['[', '2.0', ', ', '1.0', ']']
```

This uses complex numbers as the example, but you can just as easily create a class to encode dates (except I think JSON is a little fuzzy about dates).

Answer (score 11):

Here is a simple solution to over come "datetime not JSON serializable"
problem.

```
enco = lambda obj: (
    obj.isoformat()
    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime)
    or isinstance(obj, datetime.date)
    else None
)

json.dumps({'date': datetime.datetime.now()}, default=enco)
```

**Output:->** {"date": "2015-12-16T04:48:20.024609"}

Answer (score 8):

I usually use [`orjson`](https://github.com/ijl/orjson). Not only because of [its tremendous performance](https://github.com/ijl/orjson#performance), but also for [its great (RFC-3339 compliant) support of `datetime`](https://github.com/ijl/orjson#datetime):

```
import orjson # via pip3 install orjson
from datetime import datetime

data = {"created_at": datetime(2022, 3, 1)}

orjson.dumps(data) # returns b'{"created_at":"2022-03-01T00:00:00"}'
```

If you would like to use `datetime.datetime` objects without a tzinfo as UTC you can add the related option:

```
orjson.dumps(data, option=orjson.OPT_NAIVE_UTC) # returns b'{"created_at":"2022-03-01T00:00:00+00:00"}'
```

Comment: This is a great answer. No idea why the native `json` module can't handle datetime when virtually all other libraries in other languages do. This should be the standard.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to do this is to change the part of the dict that is in datetime format to *isoformat*. That value will effectively be a string in *isoformat* which *json* is OK with.

```
v_dict = version.dict()
v_dict['created_at'] = v_dict['created_at'].isoformat()
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually it is quite simple.
If you need to often serialize dates, then work with them as strings. You can easily convert them back as datetime objects if needed.

If you need to work mostly as datetime objects, then convert them as strings before serializing.

```
import json, datetime

date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
print(json.dumps(date))
"2018-12-01 15:44:34.409085"
print(type(date))
<class 'str'>

datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(datetime_obj)
2018-12-01 15:44:34.409085
print(type(datetime_obj))
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

As you can see, the output is the same in both cases. Only the type is different.

Answer (score 6):

Try this one with an example to parse it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime
import json

import dateutil.parser  # pip install python-dateutil


class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        return super(JSONEncoder, self).default(obj)


def test():
    dts = [
        datetime.datetime.now(),
        datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone(-datetime.timedelta(hours=4))),
        datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc),
    ]
    for dt in dts:
        dt_isoformat = json.loads(json.dumps(dt, cls=JSONEncoder))
        dt_parsed = dateutil.parser.parse(dt_isoformat)
        assert dt == dt_parsed
        print(f'{dt}, {dt_isoformat}, {dt_parsed}')
        # 2018-07-22 02:22:42.910637, 2018-07-22T02:22:42.910637, 2018-07-22 02:22:42.910637
        # 2018-07-22 02:22:42.910643-04:00, 2018-07-22T02:22:42.910643-04:00, 2018-07-22 02:22:42.910643-04:00
        # 2018-07-22 06:22:42.910645, 2018-07-22T06:22:42.910645, 2018-07-22 06:22:42.910645
        # 2018-07-22 06:22:42.910646+00:00, 2018-07-22T06:22:42.910646+00:00, 2018-07-22 06:22:42.910646+00:00


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) models you can directly pass `encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder` to the field constructor. It will work like a charm.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now


class Activity(models.Model):
    diff = models.JSONField(null=True, blank=True, encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder)


diff = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": "BB",
    "c": now()
}

Activity.objects.create(diff=diff)
```

Answer (score 3):

Generally there are several ways to serialize datetimes, like:

1. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string, short and can include timezone info, e.g., [jgbarah's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22238613/723090)
2. Timestamp (timezone data is lost), e.g. [JayTaylor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15823348/723090)
3. Dictionary of  properties (including timezone).

If you're okay with the last way, the [json_tricks](https://github.com/mverleg/pyjson_tricks) package handles dates, times and datetimes including timezones.

```
from datetime import datetime
from json_tricks import dumps
foo = {'title': 'String', 'datetime': datetime(2012, 8, 8, 21, 46, 24, 862000)}
dumps(foo)
```

which gives:

```
{"title": "String", "datetime": {"__datetime__": null, "year": 2012, "month": 8, "day": 8, "hour": 21, "minute": 46, "second": 24, "microsecond": 862000}}
```

So all you need to do is

```
`pip install json_tricks`
```

and then import from `json_tricks` instead of `json`.

The advantage of not storing it as a single string, int or float comes when decoding: if you encounter just a string or especially int or float, you need to know something about the data to know if it's a datetime. As a dict, you can store metadata so it can be decoded automatically, which is what `json_tricks` does for you. It's also easily editable for humans.

Disclaimer: it's made by me. Because I had the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [jjmontes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-can-i-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable/36142844#36142844), I have used the following approach.
For [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) and *flask-restful* users

```
# Get JSON string
jsonStr = json.dumps(my_dictionary, indent=1, sort_keys=True, default=str)
# Then convert the JSON string to a JSON object
return json.loads(jsonStr)
```

Comment: This not distinct from jjmontes Answer - this should be a comment on their Answer instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the result in a view be sure to return a proper response. According to the API, jsonify does the following:

> Creates a Response with the JSON representation of the given arguments
>   with an application/json mimetype.

To mimic this behavior with json.dumps you have to add a few extra lines of code.

```
response = make_response(dumps(sample, cls=CustomEncoder))
response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
response.headers['mimetype'] = 'application/json'
return response
```

You should also return a dict to fully replicate jsonify's response. So, the entire file will look like this

```
from flask import make_response
from json import JSONEncoder, dumps


class CustomEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if set(['quantize', 'year']).intersection(dir(obj)):
            return str(obj)
        elif hasattr(obj, 'next'):
            return list(obj)
        return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

@app.route('/get_reps/', methods=['GET'])
def get_reps():
    sample = ['some text', <datetime object>, 123]
    response = make_response(dumps({'result': sample}, cls=CustomEncoder))
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    response.headers['mimetype'] = 'application/json'
    return response
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with flask.

Comment: The question is about python. My answer solves the question using python. The OP did not say if the solution should include or exclude certain libraries. It is also useful for anyone else reading this question who wants an alternative to `pymongo`.

Comment: They question is both about Python and *not* about Flask. Flask is not even needed in your answer to the question, so I suggest you remove it.

Comment: In flask it's much easier to use `flask.json.dumps` it handles datetime objects.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my full solution for converting datetime to JSON and back...

```
import calendar, datetime, json

def outputJSON(obj):
    """Default JSON serializer."""

    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        if obj.utcoffset() is not None:
            obj = obj - obj.utcoffset()

        return obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    return str(obj)

def inputJSON(obj):
    newDic = {}

    for key in obj:
        try:
            if float(key) == int(float(key)):
                newKey = int(key)
            else:
                newKey = float(key)

            newDic[newKey] = obj[key]
            continue
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            newDic[str(key)] = datetime.datetime.strptime(obj[key], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            continue
        except TypeError:
            pass

        newDic[str(key)] = obj[key]

    return newDic

x = {'Date': datetime.datetime.utcnow(), 34: 89.9, 12.3: 90, 45: 67, 'Extra': 6}

print x

with open('my_dict.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(x, fp, default=outputJSON)

with open('my_dict.json') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f, object_hook=inputJSON)

print my_dict
```

Output

```
{'Date': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 8, 2, 30, 56, 479727), 34: 89.9, 45: 67, 12.3: 90, 'Extra': 6}
{'Date': datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 8, 2, 30, 56, 479727), 34: 89.9, 45: 67, 12.3: 90, 'Extra': 6}
```

JSON File

```javascript
{"Date": "2013-11-08 02:30:56.479727", "34": 89.9, "45": 67, "12.3": 90, "Extra": 6}
```

This has enabled me to import and export strings, ints, floats and datetime objects.
It shouldn't be to hard to extend for other types.

Comment: It explodes in Python 3 with `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`. It is because of `'wb'` open mode, should be `'w'`. It also blows in deserialization when we have data similar to date like `'0000891618-05-000338'` but not matching pattern.

Answer (score 2):

My solution ...

```
from datetime import datetime
import json

from pytz import timezone
import pytz


def json_dt_serializer(obj):
    """JSON serializer, by macm.
    """
    rsp = dict()
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        rsp['day'] = obj.day
        rsp['hour'] = obj.hour
        rsp['microsecond'] = obj.microsecond
        rsp['minute'] = obj.minute
        rsp['month'] = obj.month
        rsp['second'] = obj.second
        rsp['year'] = obj.year
        rsp['tzinfo'] = str(obj.tzinfo)
        return rsp
    raise TypeError("Type not serializable")


def json_dt_deserialize(obj):
    """JSON deserialize from json_dt_serializer, by macm.
    """
    if isinstance(obj, str):
        obj = json.loads(obj)
    tzone = timezone(obj['tzinfo'])
    tmp_dt = datetime(obj['year'],
                      obj['month'],
                      obj['day'],
                      hour=obj['hour'],
                      minute=obj['minute'],
                      second=obj['second'],
                      microsecond=obj['microsecond'])
    loc_dt = tzone.localize(tmp_dt)
    deserialize = loc_dt.astimezone(tzone)
    return deserialize
```

Ok, now some tests.

```
# Tests
now = datetime.now(pytz.utc)

# Using this solution
rsp = json_dt_serializer(now)
tmp = json_dt_deserialize(rsp)
assert tmp == now
assert isinstance(tmp, datetime) == True
assert isinstance(now, datetime) == True

# using default from json.dumps
tmp = json.dumps(datetime.now(pytz.utc), default=json_dt_serializer)
rsp = json_dt_deserialize(tmp)
assert isinstance(rsp, datetime) == True

# Lets try another timezone
eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
now = datetime.now(eastern)
rsp = json_dt_serializer(now)
tmp = json_dt_deserialize(rsp)

print(tmp)
# 2015-10-22 09:18:33.169302-04:00

print(now)
# 2015-10-22 09:18:33.169302-04:00

# Wow, Works!
assert tmp == now
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the `date`  to  `string`

```
date = str(datetime.datetime(somedatetimehere))
```

Comment: jjmontes answer does exactly that, but without the necessity to do it explicitly for every date...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message while writing the serialize decorator inside a Class  with sqlalchemy. So instead of :

```
Class Puppy(Base):
    ...
    @property
    def serialize(self):
        return { 'id':self.id,
                 'date_birth':self.date_birth,
                  ...
                }
```

I  simply borrowed jgbarah's idea of using isoformat() and appended the original value with isoformat(), so that it now looks like:

```
                  ...
                 'date_birth':self.date_birth.isoformat(),
                  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix if you want your own formatting

```
for key,val in sample.items():
    if isinstance(val, datetime):
        sample[key] = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(val) #you can add different formating here
json.dumps(sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

I often use IntelliJ `Evaluate Expression` tool during debugging to copy over certain objects to analyze them. The problem with that approach is that if dictionary that you try to dump has a date it's brakes and the other problem that you can't define a converter using that tool, so I come up with this one liner:

```py
json.dumps(dict_to_dump, default=lambda o: o.__str__() if isinstance(o, datetime) else None)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered the same problem when externalizing a [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) model object to dump as JSON.

Here is how you can solve it.

```
def externalize(model_obj):
  keys = model_obj._meta.get_all_field_names()
  data = {}
  for key in keys:
    if key == 'date_time':
      date_time_obj = getattr(model_obj, key)
      data[key] = date_time_obj.strftime("%A %d. %B %Y")
    else:
      data[key] = getattr(model_obj, key)
  return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def j_serial(o):     # Self-contained
    from datetime import datetime, date
    return str(o).split('.')[0] if isinstance(o, (datetime, date)) else None
```

Usage of the above utility:

```
import datetime
serial_d = j_serial(datetime.datetime.now())
if serial_d:
    print(serial_d)  # Output: 2018-02-28 02:23:15
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue today, I found something called [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html). It's a built-in library for serializing Python objects and also load it from a pickle file.

The only difference I found between `pickle` and `json` is `pickle` file is a binary file, whereas `json` is a usual text file.

And it doesn't cause any issues with datetime objects.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to adopt a concept from [FEEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_Model_and_Notation#Elements_of_the_standard) (the Friendly Enough Expression Language) defined in DMN (Decision Model Notation) - namely @strings.

Any string starting with @" and ending with " is decoded separately with FEEL decoding. Of course the sender and the receiver have to agree to this convention, but ... the code below lets you encode lots of other things as well as dates, times, date/times, timedeltas.

You can encode year/month durations and ranges (so long as you except a 4 element tuple of chr, expr, expr, chr as being a good representation of a range - where the two chrs are open/close brackets).
So, @"P4Y2M" is a duration of 4 years and 2 months. @"P2DT5H" is a timedelta of 2 days and 4 hours, @"(2021-01-02 .. 2021-12-31)" is a year range.

The following code can be used to serialize and de-serialize @strings.

```
import datetime
import pySFeel

parser = pySFeel.SFeelParser()


def convertAtString(thisString):
    # Convert an @string
    (status, newValue) = parser.sFeelParse(thisString[2:-1])
    if 'errors' in status:
        return thisString
    else:
        return newValue


def convertIn(newValue):
    if isinstance(newValue, dict):
        for key in newValue:
            if isinstance(newValue[key], int):
                newValue[key] = float(newValue[key])
            elif isinstance(newValue[key], str) and (newValue[key][0:2] == '@"') and (newValue[key][-1] == '"'):
                newValue[key] = convertAtString(newValue[key])
            elif isinstance(newValue[key], dict) or isinstance(newValue[key], list):
                newValue[key] = convertIn(newValue[key])
    elif isinstance(newValue, list):
        for i in range(len(newValue)):
            if isinstance(newValue[i], int):
                newValue[i] = float(newValue[i])
            elif isinstance(newValue[i], str) and (newValue[i][0:2] == '@"') and (newValue[i][-1] == '"'):
                newValue[i] = convertAtString(newValue[i])
            elif isinstance(newValue[i], dict) or isinstance(newValue[i], list):
                newValue[i] = convertIn(newValue[i])
    elif isinstance(newValue, str) and (newValue[0:2] == '@"') and (newValue[-1] == '"'):
        newValue = convertAtString(newValue)
    return newValue


  def convertOut(thisValue):
      if isinstance(thisValue, datetime.date):
          return '@"' + thisValue.isoformat() + '"'
      elif isinstance(thisValue, datetime.datetime):
          return '@"' + thisValue.isoformat(sep='T') + '"'
      elif isinstance(thisValue, datetime.time):
          return '@"' + thisValue.isoformat() + '"'
      elif isinstance(thisValue, datetime.timedelta):
          sign = ''
          duration = thisValue.total_seconds()
          if duration < 0:
              duration = -duration
              sign = '-'
          secs = duration % 60
          duration = int(duration / 60)
          mins = duration % 60
          duration = int(duration / 60)
          hours = duration % 24
          days = int(duration / 24)
          return '@"%sP%dDT%dH%dM%fS"' % (sign, days, hours, mins, secs)
      elif isinstance(thisValue, bool):
          return thisValue:
      elif thisValue is None:
          return thisValue:
      elif isinstance(thisValue, int):
          sign = ''
          if thisValue < 0:
              thisValue = -thisValue
              sign = '-'
          years = int(thisValue / 12)
          months = (thisValue % 12)
          return '@"%sP%dY%dM"' % (sign, years, months)
      elif isinstance(thisValue, tuple) and (len(thisValue) == 4):
          (lowEnd, lowVal, highVal, highEnd) = thisValue
          return '@"' + lowEnd + str(lowVal) + ' .. ' + str(highVal) + highEnd
      elif thisValue is None:
          return 'null'
      elif isinstance(thisValue, dict):
          for item in thisValue:
              thisValue[item] = convertOut(thisValue[item])
          return thisValue
      elif isinstance(thisValue, list):
          for i in range(len(thisValue)):
              thisValue[i] = convertOut(thisValue[i])
          return thisValue
      else:
          return thisValue
```

Answer (score -2):

I may not 100% correct but,
this is the simple way to do serialize

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime,json

sampledict = {}
sampledict['a'] = "some string"
sampledict['b'] = datetime.datetime.now()

print sampledict   # output : {'a': 'some string', 'b': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 15, 5, 15, 34, 652996)}

#print json.dumps(sampledict)

'''
output : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./jsonencodedecode.py", line 10, in <module>
    print json.dumps(sampledict)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 15, 5, 16, 17, 435706) is not JSON serializable


'''

sampledict['b'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B %d, %Y %H:%M %p")

afterdump = json.dumps(sampledict)

print afterdump  #output : {"a": "some string", "b": "April 15, 2017 05:18 AM"}

print type(afterdump) #<type 'str'>


afterloads = json.loads(afterdump) 

print afterloads # output : {u'a': u'some string', u'b': u'April 15, 2017 05:18 AM'}


print type(afterloads) # output :<type 'dict'>
```