# Bottle framework: how to return datetime in JSON response

Tags: python, json, datetime, bottle, bson

When I try to return JSON containing `datetime` value, I'm getting

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 178, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0) is not JSON serializable
```

Which is normal. Is there an easy way to add an object hook to `bottle` like

```
from bson import json_util
import json
json.dumps(anObject, default=json_util.default)
```

to get `datetime` values converted?

Comment: Why not something like `datetime.strftime(o, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python)

Comment: @arocks nope, I'm asking about bottle framework which automatically converts dicts to json data on response.

Comment: @fp I want to do this by framework tools.

Comment: Can you show us your return method?

Comment: @SyedHabibM it looks like ```return d``` where ```d``` has a type of ```dict```. ```bottle``` automatically converts dicts to json data. I need an easy way to hook this conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question! I can see a couple of ways of doing this. The one would be to write a custom plugin that wraps the `JSONPlugin`:

```
from bottle import route, run, install, JSONPlugin
from bson import json_util

class JSONDefaultPlugin(JSONPlugin):
    def __init__(self):
        super(JSONDefaultPlugin, self).__init__()
        self.plain_dump = self.json_dumps
        self.json_dumps = lambda body: self.plain_dump(body, default=json_util.default)
```

Which can then be used like this:

```
@route('/hello')
def index(name):
    return {'test': datetime.datetime(2014, 2, 1, 0, 0)}

install(JSONDefaultPlugin())
run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

And will give output like this:

```
{"test": {"$date": 1391212800000}}
```

Another, shorter, way is to simply specify the `json_loads` parameter when instantiating the JSONPlugin class:

```
import json
from bson import json_util

install(JSONPlugin(json_dumps=lambda body: json.dumps(body, default=json_util.default)))
```

This produces the same result.

#### Background

This all makes a little more sense when you look at the [source code for bottle](https://github.com/defnull/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py) (some parts removed below for brevity):

```
class JSONPlugin(object):
    name = 'json'
    api  = 2

    def __init__(self, json_dumps=json_dumps):
        self.json_dumps = json_dumps

    def apply(self, callback, route):
        dumps = self.json_dumps
        if not dumps: return callback
        def wrapper(*a, **ka):
            ... 

            if isinstance(rv, dict):
                ...
            elif isinstance(rv, HTTPResponse) and isinstance(rv.body, dict):
                rv.body = dumps(rv.body)
                rv.content_type = 'application/json'
            return rv

        return wrapper
```

All we need to do is make sure the call to `dumps` there receives the `default` keyword argument you wish to provide.

Comment: Great answer! I was too lazy to have a look at the sources :-)

Comment: or this for short `bottle.install(bottle.JSONPlugin(json_dumps=json_util.dumps))`

Answer (score 0):

A few short additions:

1. If you prefer using the standard library only, you can do:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
from functools import partial

from bottle import run

from bottle import JSONPlugin, Bottle

json_plugin = JSONPlugin(json_dumps=partial(json.dumps, default=str))
app = Bottle()
app.install(json_plugin)
```

2. If you need more sophisticated representation of `datetime`:

```
def json_serial(obj):
    """JSON serializer for objects not serializable by default json code"""

    if isinstance(obj, (datetime, date)):
        # NOT SO SOPHISTICATED, BUT BETTER THAN str
        # replace this with what ever format you need
        return obj.isoformat() 
    raise TypeError ("Type %s not serializable" % type(obj))

json_plugin = JSONPlugin(json_dumps=partial(json.dumps, default=json_serial))
```

3. Finally, if you prefer brevity:
   Because the JSON plugin is inserted to the default Bottle instance, you can do:

```
app = Bottle()
app.plugins[0].json_dumps = partial(json.dumps, default=str)
```