# Peewee model to JSON

Tags: python, json, peewee

I'm creating an API using peewee as the ORM and I need the ability to convert a peewee model object into a JSON object to send to the user. Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: Please consider changing the best answer. Take a look at the votes...

Answer (score -8, accepted):

you can do something like that:

```
class MyModel(peewee.Model):

  def __str__(self):
    r = {}
    for k in self._data.keys():
      try:
         r[k] = str(getattr(self, k))
      except:
         r[k] = json.dumps(getattr(self, k))
    return str(r)


class User(MyModel):
    email = CharField()
    status = CharField(default="enabled")
    firstname = CharField()
    lastname = CharField()
    class Meta:
        database = db
```

Comment: Remember to do `json.dumps(str(user))` and not `json.dumps(user)`

Comment: This is really not a very good way to accomplish this. I'd strongly recommend checking out Peewee's `model_to_dict()` helper that was designed exactly for this purpose. You can find the docs [here](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#model_to_dict). It also has the benefit of being able to recurse or exclude fields.

Comment: Why is this the recommended answer? StackOverflow fail.

Answer (score 113):

Peewee has a `model_to_dict` and `dict_to_model` helpers in the `playhouse.shortcuts` extension module.

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#model_to_dict
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#dict_to_model

You could use these as follows:

```
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict, dict_to_model

user_obj = User.select().where(User.username == 'charlie').get()
json_data = json.dumps(model_to_dict(user_obj))
```

Also note that `model_to_dict()` can recurse through related models, include back-referenced models, and exclude certain fields from being serialized.

Comment: @coleifar! how to import `model_to_dict()`?

Comment: `from playhouse.shortcuts import *`

Comment: `from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict, dict_to_model`

Comment: @coleifer can you use ```model_to_dict``` this way on a ```SelectQuery``` object that has multiple items (i.e. that doesn't use ```.get()``` ) ? I'm either seeing an error message like ```'SelectQuery' object has no attribute '_meta'``` or if the table contains a UUID field ```Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable```

Comment: @AdjunctProfessorFalcon  did you work out how to get around the "'UUID' is not JSON serializable"? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: In this case the UUID error is not a peewee issue but a uuid.UUID -> json.dumps not defaulting to call str or repr on a non string like object.
`import json; import uuid; x = uuid.uuid4(); json.dumps(x);` 
`Traceback (most recent call last): ... TypeError: Object of type 'UUID' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: states = list(User.select().where(State.username ** 'a%').dicts() ) use this when you get multiple rows

Answer (score 8):

#### when single fetch

```
user = User.select().where(User.id == 1).get()
model_to_dict(user)  #to Dict
```

#### when Multiple fetch

```
users = list(User.select().where(User.name ** 'a%').dicts())
```

Answer (score 4):

also, you can get model as a dict, and then convert to json with correct field types (bool, int, float, etc.):

```
import peewee
import json
from bson import json_util
from datetime import datetime

class User(peewee.Model):
    email = CharField()
    status = BooleanField(default=True)
    firstname = CharField()
    lastname = CharField()
    age = IntegerField()
    created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    class Meta:
        database = db

user = User.select().dicts().get()
print json.dumps(user, default=json_util.default)
```

Comment: If the User model had a `created = DateTimeField()` then json.dumps(user) would complain about the datetime.datetime instance not be JSON serializable. What could I do in this case with datetime fields?

Comment: @Roland try solution from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11875813/1270607):

    `from bson import json_util`
    `print json.dumps(user, default=json_util.default)`

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using mongodb. Even though, trying to use the python builtin bson I got something like `'{"born": {"$date": 1399579518000}, "name": "John Smith"}'`. And trying to use this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bson/0.3.3 crashed the application. Thanks for the tip though.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody having issues like `TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable`, this works for me (tested on Python 3.8.2).

```
from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict
import json

def print_model(model):
    print(json.dumps(model_to_dict(model), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))

def print_models(models):
    print(json.dumps(list(models.dicts()), indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str))
```

**Usage 1 - Single model**

```
for person in Person.select():
    print_model(person)
```

**Usage 2 - Many models**

```
print_models(Person.select())
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this very same problem and ended up defining my own parser extension for JSON types that could not be automatically serialized. I'm fine for now in using strings as data represented (although you could possibly use different datatypes, but beware of approximation using floating points!

In the following example, I put this in a file called `json_serialize.py` inside a `utils` folder:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import datetime

try:
    import uuid
    _use_uuid = True
except ImportError:
    _use_uuid = False

datetime_format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
date_format = "%Y/%m/%d"
time_format = "%H:%M:%S"


def set_datetime_format(fmt_string):
    datetime_format = fmt_string


def set_date_format(fmt_string):
    date_format = fmt_string


def set_time_format(fmt_string):
    time_format = fmt_string


def more(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
        return str(obj)

    if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
        return obj.strftime(datetime_format)

    if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
        return obj.strftime(date_format)

    if isinstance(obj, datetime.time):
        return obj.strftime(time_format)

    if _use_uuid and isinstance(obj, uuid.UUID):
        return str(obj.db_value())

    raise TypeError("%r is not JSON serializable" % obj)
```

Then, in my app:

```
import json
from utils import json_serialize

...


json.dumps(model_to_dict(User.get()), default=json_serialize.more)
```

edit just to add: this is very largely inspired by `json_utils.default` module found in mongodb but mainly relies on the `json` module and needs no import of mongodb own bson/json_utils module.

Usually I update it to support new types as soon as my app raises the `TypeError` for it found a type not able to serialize

Answer (score 0):

I usually implement the model to dict and dict to model functions, for maximum security and understanding of the inner workings of the code. Peewee does a lot of magic and you want to be in control over it.

The most obvious argument for why you should not iterate on the fields but rather explicitly specify them is because of security considerations. Not all fields can be exposed to the user, and I assume you need this functionality to implement some sort of REST API.

So - you should do something like this:

```
class UserData(db.Model):
    user = db.ForeignKeyField(User)
    data = db.CharField()

    def serialize():
        # front end does not need user ID here
        return {
            'data': self.data
        }

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data):
        UserData.create(
            # we enforce user to be the current user
            user=current_user,
            data=json_data['data']
        )
```