# Get full result back from PeeWee query (for conversion to JSON)

Tags: python, json, peewee

I am trying to render a PeeWee query result as `JSON` using the following code:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    c = Category.select().order_by(Category.name).get()
    return jsonify(model_to_dict(c))
```

Doing this I only get one row back from the query. I'm pretty sure the issue is my use of `get()`, which the docs clearly say only returns one row. What do I use in place of `get()` to fetch the *entire* results back?

This question below pointed me in the right direction, but is is also using `get()`

[Peewee model to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975920/peewee-model-to-json)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is that the query needs to be iterated to fetch each row; and that get() is shorthand for fetching the first row. I was thinking that there might be an alternative to get() that didn't require the explicit iteration. I don't think there is. Right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What do I use in place of get() to fetch the entire results back?

Modify your code to be:

```
query = Category.select().order_by(Category.name)
return jsonify({'rows':[model_to_dict(c) for c in query]})
```

Alternatively, you could do:

```
query = Category.select().order_by(Category.name).dicts()
return jsonify({'rows':list(query)})
```

Comment: Had to modify jsonify's return value to be a dictionary. See this q/a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435297/how-do-i-jsonify-a-list-in-flask.  Thanks, Charlie, you got me moving foward.

Comment: Thank you. I search for this exact problem, and it take me a while to get to your answer. Work like charm now.