# Return single peewee record as dict

Tags: python, peewee

If I'm getting multiple records from a database with peewee, I can convert them to dicts like this:

```
users = User.select().where(User.attribute == some_value).dicts()
```

However, often I only want one record (or know that only one record will be returned), so I can do:

```
one_user = User.get(User.name == some_value)
```

But I can't call `.dicts()` on the object which is returned by that.
Is there a way to get the result of that get query in dict form?

At the moment the only thing I can think of is the unpythonic

```
one_user = User.select().where(User.name == some_value).dicts()[0]
```

Comment: I don't know `peewee` but maybe you can call `vars` on the result: `one_user = vars(one_user)`

Comment: i think your question is closely related to this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975920/peewee-model-to-json

you can create anothermodel which can convert your user to a json

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use ".get()":

```
one_user = User.select().where(User.name == some_value).dicts().get()
```

Though you can also add a helper method:

```
class User(Model):
    @classmethod
    def get_as_dict(cls, expr):
        query = cls.select().where(expr).dicts()
        return query.get()
```

It's python. You can extend it.

Answer (score 28):

`peewee` has an extension function [**`model_to_dict`**](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#model_to_dict), defined in `playhouse.shortcuts`. From the example:

```
>>> from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict

>>> user = User.create(username='charlie')
>>> model_to_dict(user)
{'id': 1, 'username': 'charlie'}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I am new to `peewee` and have just gone from the documentation. How can I improve my answer? Always happy to help. Thanks.

Comment: It's `from playhouse.shortcuts import model_to_dict`. You might got a downvote because it isn't working.

Answer (score -3):

in reference to [Peewee model to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975920/peewee-model-to-json)

i think you should implement a **str** method as defined in the link, and then when you do.

`user = User.get(User.name == some_value)`

`userDict = json.dumps(str(user))`

you will get the dictioanry of the user