# how to change datetime to string in sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

this is my code, query Notification.create_time

```
result = session.query(
        Notification.content, cls.is_read,
        Notification.create_time).join(
        cls, Notification.id == cls.notification).filter(
            and_(cls.user == user_id)).order_by(
                Notification.create_time.desc()).all()
```

in other place need to json.dumps query result to frontend, datetime format cann't json.dumps, so I want to do like this:

```
session.query(Notification.create_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

so, how to change datetime to string in sqlalchemy query?

Comment: That'd be DB specific. Postgresql for example uses [`to_char`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) for timestamp formatting, which you could call using [`sqlalchemy.func`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html). But the (imo) better solution would be to [use a JSON serializer that handles `datetime` objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285558/datetime-date2014-4-25-is-not-json-serializable-in-django).

Comment: you are awesome, thank you very much.my idea go to a wrong way.XD

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Can use `func.to_char()` (in postgres, not sure about mysql) to convert a datetime to a string, something like:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
session.query(func.to_char(Notification.create_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))
```

But the better way it to set up your json serializer to handle things like datetimes, [as is described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python)

Comment: This format worked for me 'Dy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS' in Postgres

Comment: It works on Oracle too. Thank you :)

Comment: Here are the values used by Oracle: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

Comment: Yes, correct format for me func.to_char(User.birthday, 'YYYY-MM-DD')