# How to convert cqlengine resultset objects into JSON format

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cqlengine

I am writing an API which queries a Cassandra 2.1.2 based database and returns results in JSON format. I am using cqlengine for this.

Here is the simplified schema -

```
class Checkins(Model):
    Model.__comment__ = "Table mapping for submit datastore"
    changelist     =  columns.Integer (primary_key= True)                                 # Changelist number
    checkin_date   =  columns.DateTime()                                                  # Submit time
    stream_name    =  columns.Ascii   (primary_key= True)                                 # Stream-name
    creator        =  columns.Ascii   ()                                                  # Creator
```

My query is this

```
clobj = Checkins.objects(changelist=changelist).get()
```

How do I convert the resultset into a json format ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [dictionaries from models](http://cqlengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/models.html?highlight=dict#manipulating-model-instances-as-dictionaries) as of cqlengine 0.12.  From there you can use the json module to get a JSON format.  You do have to be careful because datetimes are not json serializable.  Therefore you will need to convert it to a string first (Or look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python) for other ways to fix the datetime serialization problem).

```
import json

clobj = Checkins.objects(changelist=changelist).get()
clobj_dict = dict(clobj_dict)
clobj_dict['checkin_date'] = str(clobj_dict['checkin_date'])
json_string = json.dumps(clobj_dict)
```

or you could add it as a property on the class

```
import json

class Checkins(Model):
    # Define your model as before
    # ...

    @property
    def json(self):
        # Perform the same thing as before.
        json_dict = dict(self)
        json_dict['checkin_date'] = str(json_dict['checkin_date'])
        return json.dumps(clobj_dict)

# Just call the property.
clobj = Checkins.objects(changelist=changelist).get()
json_string = clobj.json
```