# Datetime is not json serializable, using tastypie

Tags: python, json, django, tastypie

This is my time_now() function

```
def time_now():
    return timezone.now()
```

I call it to init created_at filed of my SkyGroupResource
with the following way:

```
def obj_create(self,bundle,**kwargs):

    return super(SkyGroupResource, self).obj_create(bundle, owner_id=bundle.request.user.skyuser, created_at = time_tools.time_now())
```

In other resource, I have the following field:

```
group_id = fields.ForeignKey(SkyGroupResource,'group_id',null=False)
```

when I'm trying to use my second resorce on POST , I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 19, 19, 51, 33, 8253,
>   tzinfo=) is not JSON serializable

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the date to a string first, using e.g. `str(datetime.now())`.

*Edit: you should have a look at: [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable" in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python).