# How to store time without date in Python so it's convenient to compare?

Tags: python, datetime

I have a simple task of storing a time in server's timezone and then comparing if current time if after or before the saved time.

I tried to store the time as a "Jan 1st 2008" date with the time I need. The problem is a daylight saving time gets in a way, if I save "16:00" on Jan 1st and try to compare it with "16:00" on April 1st I get an one hour difference. I want "16:00" to always mean current day's "16:00".

What would be an efficient and reliable way of storing and comparing time of the day and ignoring the date? I need it to also be json-serializable, so I can easily manipulate the value in python and JS if needed.

Comment: Do you just want the hour/minute/sec differences?

Comment: The [`datetime.time` object](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#time-objects) is independent of any particular day.

Comment: Do you need to make comparisons across midnight? If not, a simple integer counting the minutes or seconds might be enough.

Comment: Caclulate everything in UTC, it doesn't have problems with DST by definition.

Comment: UTC doesn't have problems, only how do I represent 16:00 in UTC exactly? datetime.time is independent, but how do I store it in json? Converting everything into seconds from midnight works but I feel it's not what one would call convenient.

Comment: @serg How about `strftime` for serialization and `strptime` for deserialization? `datetime.time(13, 30).strftime('%H:%M')` resolves to `"13:30".

Comment: @user3159253 It sounds to me like doing calculations in UTC would exacerbate the problem here. Sounds like the OP specifically wants to compare local wall times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just store it however you want, then use the `.time()` method of the `datetime` objects and make comparisons.

```
from datetime import datetime
dt1 = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 16, 0, 0)
dt2 = datetime(2008, 4, 7, 13, 30, 0)

print(dt1.time() > dt2.time())    # True
```

You can also just turn your datetimes into naive datetime objects if you want to do "wall clock" arithmetic on them (as opposed to "timeline" arithmetic, which should be done with UTC `datetime`s):

```
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import datetime
NEW_YORK = tz.gettz('America/New_York')
dt = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 16, 0, tzinfo=NEW_YORK)
dt_naive = dt.replace(tzinfo=None)   # datetime(2008, 1, 1, 16)
```

Comment: You could import datetime.time and instanceate it with parameters hours, minutes, seconds, like: time(13, 30, 0)

Comment: @Arĥimedeςℳontegasppαℭacilhας Yes, but the OP was saying they have full dates with time zones.

Comment: So something like `datetime.strptime("16:00", "%H:%M").time() > datetime.now().time()`?

Comment: @serg If all you're storing is the wall time, you can use `datetime.time.strptime` directly and you'll already have a `time` object which can be compared to other `time` objects.

Comment: Can you please clarify how having a string "16:00" I can compare it to the  current time? Currently the time is 9:24, `print datetime.now().time()` returns  `16:24:16.763842`, while `print datetime.strptime("16:00", "%H:%M").time()` returns `16:00:00`. I can't simply compare the two time() as it compares not what I expect.

Comment: @serg What exactly are you expecting? `datetime.strptime("16:00", "%H:%M").time() > datetime(2016, 4, 6, 16, 24, 16).time()` returns `False` for me, as I would expect.

Comment: I'm expecting "16:00" to be "bigger" than "9:24", it's currently smaller because it's comparing "16:00" with "16:24".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108308/discussion-between-paul-and-serg).

Comment: Sorry just realized that in my local env I had system timezone to be UTC, unlike on the server where it's PDT.

Comment: If you don't need utc time; you could use a naive datetime object (there is no need to pass `tzinfo=NEW_YORK`). If you need to know both utc and local time then you should use `pytz` timezones (such as produced by `tzlocal.get_localzone()`).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I was demonstrating how to create a native datetime from a time zone aware one, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You have said this before and you are wrong. dateutil time zones only have problems dealing with ambiguous times. This will be solved in the next point release, but there are issues with sorting DST in the time zone itself.

Comment: I should also note that tzinfo objects are not really intended to be able to resolve ambiguous times. This is the problem solved by PEP495. pytz and (in the master branch) dateutil are basically implementing a bit of a hack to make up for an oversight in datetime objects.

Comment: @Paul: 1- there are ambiguous times and therefore the code must deal with it (e.g., you may leave a comment that the code may produce a wrong result during such times and hope that your users won't suffer too much because of it) 2- `pytz` timezones allow to perform the round-trip `utc -> local time -> utc` while `dateutil` timezones do not. You do not need PEP 495 for that.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian This is way off topic, but it's a trade off in many ways because it's a hack. Consider that pytz fails to properly handle arithmetic over a DST transition, which dateutil does. We can meet in chat if you want to talk about this further. Either way, it has literally zero bearing on this answer, which doesn't even use timezone aware datetimes, and has no need to make UTC-> Aware->UTC round trips on ambiguous times even if it did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108449/discussion-between-paul-and-j-f-sebastian).

Comment: @Paul 1- you use `tzinfo=NEW_YORK` in your answer. My comments say that it is either *unnecessary* (if you don't care about UTC time)  or wrong (if you do care about local <-> UTC conversions) — you don't control the input time.  2- `pytz` supports arithmetic across DST boundaries (that is why `.notmalize()` method exists). You shouldn't believe everything you read on the Internet (even statements from people who should know better).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian My example was *how to remove a time zone*. It could have been literally any `tzinfo` object. Even if I did need that to be a NY time zone, the time was specified, it was *not ambiguous* and so perfectly acceptable. Your bizarre insistence that `dateutil` timezones are somehow unusable because they do not (in the latest release) support something that time zone objects were never designed to support seems inappropriate to me, and is definitely out of place here.

Comment: @Paul 1- I comment on the answer as it is  — not as it might have been and the answer does use dateutil timezone with a non-fixed UTC offset. 2- As I said: you don't control the input i.e., `16:00` is not the only possible input time. In general, the input time may be ambiguous. Why are insisting that there are no ambiguous times?  3- no released `dateutil` version handles UTC `<->` local conversions correctly (it is a fact: run the test from #112 issue on github, to confirm it). You  shouldn't use such words as "bizarre" — it is demeaning.  The issues are real as you know it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It's a real issue (one that I personally fixed, mind you) but it only applies in a very specific edge case. If you had used a pytz time zone in my example, it would have had literally the same effect. There was 0 problem with what I showed. Additionally, if you had done an operation on that to turn it into an ambiguous time, `pytz` would have failed also, so it's ridiculous to imagine that clear non-edge cases like this somehow mean that dateutil time zones are unusable.

Comment: 2- it is incorrect that pytz and dateutil are the same here. The essential difference is that dateutil may produce a wrong result *silently* for a case that happens every single year in many common  timezones (that might be ok in some cases. But an application should be able to choose). pytz's `.localize(is_dst=None)` call that I've mentioned earlier raises an exception in such cases. The application is free to resolve the ambiguity differently by passing a different `is_dst` value.

Comment: 3- if you want to compare pytz and dateutil's  timezone support: pytz supports UTC -> local -> UTC round-trip while even the latest dateutil version doesn't.  Note: a user doesn't need to pass `is_dst` in this case because the source UTC timezone has a fixed UTC offset (zero). It is unrelated to the question but you've raised the issue — I just answer to incorrect assumptions  in your comments.

Comment: I am making no incorrect assumptions. That simply does not apply in this case. No UTC->local->UTC transitions take place in this code so there is no need to warn about them. If you need to make those transitions and want to use dateutil time zones in case you run across an ambiguous time, you can use the master dev branch of dateutil.

Answer (score 13):

> I need it to also be json-serializable, so I can easily manipulate the value in python and JS if needed.

`"16:00"` string could be used to store the time (if you don't need seconds).

> I want "16:00" to always mean current day's "16:00".

To compare it with the current time:

```
import time

if time.strftime('%H:%M') < '16:00':
    print('before 4pm')
else:
    print('after 4pm')
```

`%H`, `%M` produce zero-padded decimal numbers such as `07` and therefore the string comparison works correctly. It works in the presence of DST transitions too (as long as C `localtime()` works).

To parse it into time, datetime objects:

```
from datetime import datetime

four_pm_time = datetime.strptime('16:00', '%H:%M').time()
four_pm = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), four_pm_time)
```

To get a timezone-aware datetime object:

```
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

four_pm_aware = tzlocal.get_localzone().localize(four_pm, is_dst=None)
```

[To get Unix time corresponding to 4pm (assuming `mktime()` works here)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36462784/4279):

```
import time

unix_time = time.mktime(time.localtime()[:3] + (16, 0, 0) + (-1,)*3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `datetime.time` object (as @ChrisP also pointed out in a comment). For example:

```py
import datetime

time1 = datetime.time(hour=16, minute=12)
time2 = datetime.time(hour=4, minute=11)
```

(note that times are given in 24 hour format - i.e., `hour` can go up to 23)

Now you can compare times, for example:

```py
print(time1 > time2)
```

Outputs `True` as expected. Note that you can also include seconds:

```py
time3 = datetime.time(hour=16, minute=12, second=42)
```

and that `time3 > time1` as expected. Similarly, you can use the `microsecond` argument for even more precision. If you need timezones too, you can pass in a `datetime.tzinfo` object by using the `tzinfo` argument.

Finally, `datetime.time` is not directly JSON-serializable, but then again, neither is `datetime.datetime`. However, this can be overcome easily (see other options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)), like so:

```py
import json

s = json.dumps(time1.isoformat())
```

and in reverse (reading):

```py
json.loads(datetime.time.fromisoformat(s.strip("'")))
```

(here we strip the additional quotes or else we'll get an error)