# Write a python script to generate a timestamp ( unix epoch value) each day at a give time

Tags: python, timestamp

I want to write a small python which needs to generate a simple precise timestamp  each day ( the script will be run each day) at a particular hour say 1pm. I wrote something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.utcnow() # Current time
then = datetime(1970,1,1) # 0 epoch time
ts = now - then
ts = ts.days * 24 * 3600 + ts.seconds
print ts
```

This is good, but i want to pass `now` for the time_field that i on daily basis. How do I do this?

Comment: It is a little unclear for me what you want to do. What is `time_field `?

Comment: `now` is the date and time. `ts = now - then` is the duration since `then`... what exactly do you want?

Comment: my end result should be a timestamp which must be generated EACH day at 1pm (say) . since the above code gives the Current TIME , i want a timestamp at a particular hour of day.

Comment: What's wrong with [**`time.time()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `time.mktime` function:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=13, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> print(dt)
2016-04-06 13:00:00
>>> time.mktime(dt.timetuple())
1459944000.0
```

If you need to be timezone-aware, use a timezone-aware datetime's `utctimetuple` method and the `time.gmtime` function.

(edited to show how to create datetime.datetime for a specific time)

Comment: The time part is good, but the script needs to run daily, so i want the DATA part to be picked up dynamically from system

Comment: @PythonFreak you want to use a datetime for "today" at 13:00?

Comment: @PythonFreak: note: a given local time may be ambiguous or even non-existent (e.g., during DST transitions). Also, `mktime()` may use an incorrect timezone definition for a given date/time on some platforms (if `mktime()` has no access to the historical tz database on a given platform and depending on how long your script is running). You could [use `tzlocal.get_localzone()` in a portable code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36462784/4279)

Answer (score 0):

`date` command in shell gives us epoch time also.

```
date +%s
```

So write your python script as

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['date', '+%s'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print out
```

and then call it daily with the same logic you are using now.

Comment: Which shell? Which OS?

Comment: date +%s gives me the current data,, i want the data for a particular time , read the question

Comment: you run it at any time, like you run it at 8am, but you need epoch of 1pm? @PythonFreak

Answer (score 0):

To generate a POSIX timestamp that corresponds to `1pm`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
import tzlocal # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = tzlocal.get_localzone()
now = datetime.now(local_timezone)
one_pm = local_timezone.localize(datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 13),  # 1pm
        is_dst=None) # assert that there is no DST transition at 1pm
posix_time = one_pm.timestamp()
```

If there is no [`datetime.timestamp()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) on your Python version then it is easy to implement it for a timezone-aware datetime object such as `one_pm`:

```
def posix_timestamp(aware, epoch=datetime(1970, 1, 1)):
    utc = aware.replace(tzinfo=None) - aware.utcoffset() # convert to utc
    return (utc - epoch).total_seconds()
```

If there is no DST transition at 1pm and `mktime()` uses a correct timezone definition on a given platform then to get Unix time that corresponds to 1pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time

unix_time = time.mktime(time.localtime()[:3] + (13, 0, 0) + (-1,)*3)
```