# AWS cloudformation python not JSON serializable Error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, serialization, aws-lambda

Im using AWS lambda(using python 2.7) to invoke StackResource api to get the Stack Id of the resource created as part of nested stack .Im getting below error

**"An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: cloudformation.StackResource(stack_name='Mystack', logical_id='Ec2Stack') is not JSON serializable"**

```
import boto3
import time
import json

cloudformation = boto3.resource('cloudformation')
stack_resource = cloudformation.StackResource('prodUpgradeForchestartorFullStack','ApplicationStack')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return stack_resource
```

i have tried describe_stack_resources api which gives below error

**"An error occurred during JSON serialization of response: datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 12, 15, 23, 16, 451000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) is not JSON serializable"**

```
import boto3
import time
import json

client = boto3.client('cloudformation')


response = client.describe_stack_resources(
    StackName='Mystack',
    LogicalResourceId='Ec2Stack'
)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return response
```

Please suggest!

Comment: Is it possible for you to get a look at the format of the data that comes out of response? It's possible you might have to do some parsing to turn it into something json friendly.

Comment: That's wat I'm trying to do which I'm unable to do

Comment: This is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable-in-python