# Upgrading Flask-RESTful and the settings object is gone. How to format dates now?

Tags: python, rest, datetime, flask, flask-restful

I need to update an application from Flask-RESTful 0.2.5 to 0.3.5.

My API has over 40 endpoints, approximately 25 of which have entities that have datetime fields in them. When using 0.2.5, I followed the excellent provided in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770) and placed the following function in my `__init__.py` file:

```
class MyApiJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, (datetime.datetime, datetime.date, datetime.time)):
            return obj.isoformat()
        elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

flask.ext.restful.representations.json.settings["cls"] = MyApiJsonEncoder
```

and this worked wonderfully. Now when upgrading to 0.3.5, the settings object is no more.

```
File ".........../api/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
  flask.ext.restful.representations.json.settings["cls"] = MyApiJsonEncoder
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'settings'
```

Okay, so I looked into the documentation and found that I should be using `@marshal_with`. But this scares me! It appears that I have to go into every single endpoint that has a date or datetime field and put in a fields dictionary with a `@marshal_with` decorator. In fact, it appears that this dictionary not just state that I want my dates and datetimes in ISO8601 format but that other fields must be designated with their marshalling preferences as well.

I hope I am reading this wrong.

My question is: how can I, with Flask-RESTful 0.3.5, state globally, and *non-instrusively*, that I want all dates to be marshalled in ISO8601 format. (By non-intrusively I mean I don't want to muck up my existing 40 endpoints.)

Answer (score 0):

You now set the encoder as the `cls` property of a dict set as the `RESTFUL_JSON` attribute of the application configuration.

An explanation of how to set this attribute is [here](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/extending.html).