# How to write text with Date to JSON file without serializing it

Tags: python, json

I am reading some text from a plain text file. After doing some modifications, I want to write another file containing JSON which also has date format in it.

When I try to convert it to JSON using `json.dumps`, it gives:

> Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

When I seralise it and write it to file, it works fine. But now the date is represented in string format. I want to be in `JSON ISO date format`.

Here is my code:

```python
def getDatetimeFromISO(s):
    d = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
    return d

with open('./parsedFiles/Data.json','w+') as f:
    parsedData = []

    for filename in os.listdir('./Data'): 
        parsed = {}
        parsed["Id"] = filename[:-4]
        breakDown = []
        with open('./castPopularityData/'+str(filename),'r') as f1:
            data = ast.literal_eval(f1.read())
            for i in range(0,len(data)):
                data[i]["date"] = getDatetimeFromISO(data[i]['date'])
                data[i]["rank"] = data[i]['rank']
                breakDown.append(data[i])
            parsed["breakDown"] = breakDown    
        parsedData.append(parsed)
        print(parsedData)
    json.dump(parsedData, f, indent=4)
```

How can i write the ISO date to JSON file?

I don't want to serialize my data, which makes date format into string. I want to write dates as dates itself to JSON file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Comment: @str no it doesn't help as it is saying me to serialize before writing to file which when i do i shows date as string format instead of dateFormat

Comment: JSON does not support dates. You can either store your dates as ISO strings or use a different data format than json.

Comment: what formats does json support ?

Comment: See http://json.org.

Comment: "what formats does JSON support"...strings, numbers and booleans, pretty much. And objects and arrays to hold them in, obviously. So your date will just become a string when serialised to JSON.

Answer (score 3):

JSON is ignorant of any date or time type. See the [table of Python types and how they map to JSON data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table).

To represent any type not native to JSON (such as a date or date+time) in JSON, you must serialise it: convert that value to a sequence of characters with some specific format.

The [`json.JSONEncoder` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) allows for extension to meet this need:

> To extend this to recognize other objects, subclass and implement a `default` method with another method that returns a serializable object for `o` if possible, otherwise it should call the superclass implementation (to raise `TypeError`).

You have chosen the ISO 8601 serialisation format for representing date values; that is a good choice. The `datetime.date` type [directly supports serialising to ISO representation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat).

So now you need a JSONEncoder subclass that will recognise `datetime.date` values, and serialise them as ISO 8601:

```python
import datetime
import json

class MySpecificAppJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    """ JSON encoder for this specific application. """

    def default(self, obj):
        result = NotImplemented
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.date):
            result = obj.isoformat()
        else:
            result = json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
        return result
```

Now your function can use that encoder class:

```python
json.dump(parsed_data, outfile, indent=4, cls=MySpecificAppJSONEncoder)
```