# Flask and handeling a Zeep response with datetime

Tags: python, web-services, flask, flask-restful, zeep

I'm calling a SOAP WebService using [Zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/), and it returns a JSON-like response with a `datetime` object. I want to write a micro-service using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) and return proper JSON response. However, Flask complains that:

```
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class foo(Resource):
    def get(self, x):
        zeepResponse = {
            'Response': {
                'Number': x,
                'DateTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                'Other': None
            }
        }
        return zeepResponse

api.add_resource(foo, '/post/<int:x>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

To test from the command line, simply run:

```sh
% curl http://localhost:5000/post/911
```

Would you guide me how to convert `zeepResponse` (and the `datetime` specifically) to a proper JSON serializable structure?

Comment: JSON doesn't have a datetime type...

Comment: @thebjorn Ok. Zeep returns JSON-like structure, then. How can I convert it to proper JSON? Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON-like structure", something is either JSON data (i.e. an utf-8 encoded string) or data that is JSON serializable by a particular json serializer.  The serializer you're using, at least in the configuration that you are using it in, does not consider datetimes json serializable (because, again, datetime is not one of the types defined in the JSON definition).  How _you_ want to serialize datetimes all depends on how you design your api. ISO 8601 formatted UTC is always a good choice, maybe try that..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `json.dumps(zeepResponse, default=str)` seems to fix my problem. From [Stack Overflow 11875770](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable/36142844#36142844)

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import datetime
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class foo(Resource):
    def get(self, x):
        zeepResponse = {
            'Response': {
                'Number': x,
                'DateTime': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                'Other': None
            }
        }
        return json.loads(json.dumps(zeepResponse, default=str))

api.add_resource(foo, '/post/<int:x>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```