# Question: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, postgresql, cursor, django-managers

Facing this issue file querying data from database, I am not using serializer, but using cursor in raw query on manager as you see.

**view.py**

```
@login_required
def index(request):
if not request.user.is_superuser:
raise(404)    
customers = Customer.objects.Customer_List()
context = {'customers':  json.dumps(customers)} 
return JsonResponse(context=context, safe=False)
```

**model.py**

```
class CustomerListManager(models.Manager):
def Customer_List(self):
    from django.db import connection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("""
            select 
            customer_id
            ,last_30_days-perivous_30_days pace  
            ,first_name  
            ,last_name
            ,company
            ,tags
            ,date_created 
            ,latest_order_date
            ,first_order_date
            ,customer_group
            ,store_type
            ,assigned_to
            ,total_orders
            ,days_active 
            ,ofa
            ,ofaa
            ,total_spent
            ,average_order_value    
            ,status         
            from (              
                select 
                customer_id
                ,last_60_days-last_30_days perivous_30_days
                ,last_30_days  
                ,first_name  
                ,last_name
                ,company
                ,tags
                ,date_created 
                ,latest_order_date
                ,first_order_date
                ,customer_group
                ,store_type
                ,assigned_to
                ,total_orders
                ,days_active 
                ,ofa
                ,ofaa
                ,total_spent
                ,average_order_value    
                ,status
                from 
                    (select 
                    c.customer_id
                    ,c.first_name  
                    ,c.last_name 
                    ,c.company
                    ,c.tags
                    ,c.date_created
                    ,max(s.date_created) latest_order_date
                    ,min(s.date_created) first_order_date
                    ,g.name as customer_group
                    ,c.store_type
                    ,a.username assigned_to

                    ,(select count(s1.sale_id)  
                    from sales_sale s1  
                    where s1.customer_id =c.customer_id) total_orders

                    --,max(s.date_created) - min(s.date_created) days_active
                    ,( select max(s.date_created) - min(s.date_created)    
                        from  sales_sale s 
                        where c.customer_id=s.customer_id ) days_active

                    ,(select (max(s.date_created) - min(s.date_created))/count(s.sale_id) OFA
                    from sales_sale s 
                    where s.customer_id =c.customer_id) ofa

                    ,(select (current_date - max(s.date_created))- ( (max(s.date_created) - min(s.date_created))/count(s.sale_id) ) OFA_threshold
                    from sales_sale s 
                    where s.customer_id =c.customer_id) ofaa

                    ,(select sum(s1.total_inc_tax) total_spent  
                    from sales_sale s1  
                    where s1.customer_id =c.customer_id
                    and status != 'Cancelled' ) total_spent

                    ,(select count(s1.sale_id)  
                    from sales_sale s1  
                    where s1.customer_id = c.customer_id
                    and  s1.date_created > current_date - interval '30' day
                    ) last_30_days                                        

                    ,(select count(s1.sale_id)  
                    from sales_sale s1  
                    where s1.customer_id =c.customer_id
                    and s1.date_created > current_date - interval '60' day
                    ) last_60_days                                        

                    ,(select avg(s1.total_inc_tax) average_order_value   
                    from sales_sale s1  
                    where s1.customer_id =c.customer_id) average_order_value 
                    ,current_date - max(s.date_created) status

                    from customers_customer c
                    left outer join customers_customergroup g on c.customer_group_id=g.id 
                    left outer join auth_user a on c.assigned_to_id=a.id                                                 
                    left outer join sales_sale s on c.customer_id=s.customer_id 
                    left outer join sales_saleitem si on  s.id=si.sale_id
                    -- where c.customer_id =5
                    group by c.customer_id,c.first_name,c.last_name,c.company
                    ,c.store_credit,c.date_created,g.name,a.username
                    order by c.customer_id
                )total
                --where total.total_order >= 1
            )total2

            """)
        columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]

        result =  [
            dict(zip(columns, row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
        print(result)
    return result
```

Error:

> TypeError at /customers/
>   Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

I am trying query data from db using cursor in manager (django model)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)