# Datetime and files

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, datetime

I want to save `datetime.now()` to a json file where I can then later open the json file and convert that back to a json file. Is there a built in function for something like this? so heres what I think

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
data = {}
data['posted-time'] = datetime.now()
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

If I were to load back in that json with `json.load(f)` would it still be a date time object and if not, how do I make it one?

Comment: Refer this answer. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Comment: use `data['posted-time'] = str(datetime.now())`

Comment: How to i convert this back to a datetime object?

Comment: from datetime object to string, use `strftime`, from string to datetime object, use `strptime`. for format codes, see https://strftime.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on using JSON then following can be a solution for you:
Snippet to dump the data:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime
data = {}
data['posted-time'] = str(datetime.now())
with open("test.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

Snippet to load the data as a datetime object

```py
with open("test.json", "r") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
time = datetime.strptime(d["posted-time"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

In case you want to use custom format for date and time you would need to use strftime while dumping the data.
Another way around this can be to use pickle:

```py
import pickle
time_d = {
    "posted_time": datetime.now()
}
with open("file.dat", 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(time_d, f)
with open("file.dat", "rb") as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
print(type(data["posted_time"]))
```

This will output: 
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use date time encoder and decoder for the same. please refer below code

```
from datetime import datetime
import json
from json import JSONDecoder
from json import JSONEncoder

obj = {'name':'foo', 'type': 'bar','date':datetime.now()}


class DateTimeDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        JSONDecoder.__init__(self, object_hook=self.dict_to_object,
                             *args, **kargs)
    
    def dict_to_object(self, d): 
        if '__type__' not in d:
            return d

        type = d.pop('__type__')
        try:
            dateobj = datetime(**d)
            return dateobj
        except:
            d['__type__'] = type
            return d

class DateTimeEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    """ Instead of letting the default encoder convert datetime to string,
        convert datetime objects into a dict, which can be decoded by the
        DateTimeDecoder
    """
        
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return {
                '__type__' : 'datetime',
                'year' : obj.year,
                'month' : obj.month,
                'day' : obj.day,
                'hour' : obj.hour,
                'minute' : obj.minute,
                'second' : obj.second,
                'microsecond' : obj.microsecond,
            }   
        else:
            return JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)

            
j = json.loads(json.dumps(obj,cls=DateTimeEncoder), cls=DateTimeDecoder)
print(j['date'])
print(type(j['date']))
```

Ref : [Link](https://gist.github.com/abhinav-upadhyay/5300137)