# MongoDb not recognizing json

Tags: python, mongodb

So I'm trying to save my block into mongodb but I'm getting this error I've already tried all the answers on google/stackoverflow/some other sites but I'm not getting the same results as everyone else. Am I missing something?

```
import json
from bson import json_util

client = pymongo.MongoClient("****")

blockData = json.dumps(p1.get_latest_block().__dict__, default=json_util.default)
print(blockData)

db = client.blockchain
block = db.blocks

block.insert_one(blockData)
```

This is the block data

```
{
  "_id":1,
  "index_no":1,
  "data":"John",
    "timestamp":{
      "$date":1593037993478
    },
  "previous_hash":0,
  "hash":"090c384953d601ecda0d12f4cade9f2fb81029739b4642db900b75e56d7f55b6",
  "nonce":37
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling json.dumps?

Comment: I was following this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable

Comment: That is for serialization to extended json. When you insert data no serialization is needed (nor is it correct to attempt it). pymongo has usage examples in its documentation, if you haven't read those I suggest you start there.

Comment: Its cause block is an object, so I'm trying to change it to json

Comment: If you want to store an object, store the object as it is.