# How to overcome TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

**PreFile :**

```
  PreFile = {
         "Preferences": {
                "Quotas": {
                          "Rate limit": 0,
                          "Reset time": "2020-10-28 10:57:21.482911"
                           }
            }
     }
```

**My code:**

```
    PrefFile["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"] = data_option
       with open(Preferences_Path, 'w') as Preferences_File:
           json.dump(PrefFile, Preferences_File, indent=4, sort_keys=True)

 
    PreResetTime = PreFile["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"]
    ResetTime = datetime.strptime(PreResetTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

**Error output:**
TypeError: `Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable`

```
  File "main_functions.py", line 158, in updating_preferences
    json.dump(PrefFile, Preferences_File, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
```

I'm going to use `ResetTime` later in the program

```
if(ResetTime < (time_now - timedelta(hours=24))):
      code...
```

What can I do to overcome this error?
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Where does the typeError comes from ? Pleas share the code that generates the error

Comment: Just spit-balling here, but shouldn't your `PreResetTime` be set to `PreFile[0]["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"]`?  JSON is usually 0-indexed, but it depends on the library you're using to parse it.

Comment: @kn0wmad1c It's just working fine with ```["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"]```

Comment: did u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable?

Comment: convert your `data_option` to string before updating `PrefFile["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"]`

Comment: @ombk I did! But I did not understand it :/

Comment: @MalekGara-Hellal no prob, making sure it isnt a duplicate

Comment: @Shijith Thank you soooo much bro
It worked!
May you post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this line:

```
PrefFile["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"] = data_option
```

Change to this or similar:

```
PrefFile["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"] = data_option.isoformat()
```

https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Answer (score 0):

convert your `data_option` to string before updating `PrefFile["Preferences"]["Quotas"]["Reset time"]`
Answer by @Shijith