# Writing to a json file when date.time in payload using python

Tags: python, json, serialization

I want to write to a json file.

This is what I receive when I call the create_access_key method from boto3.

```
data_payload =
{
    'AccessKey': {
        'UserName': 'string',
        'AccessKeyId': 'string',
        'Status': 'Active'|'Inactive',
        'SecretAccessKey': 'string',
        'CreateDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

This is my function

```
def write_to_file(data):
    with open('./credentials.json', "w") as fp:
        json.dump(iam.create_access_key(
                UserName=data 
            ), fp
        )
```

There are a lot of posts out there and I did try using solutions shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable/36142844#36142844), no luck writing the CreateDate value as well.

What am I missing?

**Update**

I've found a solution, but it just seams silly and the transformation and processing is insane, there should be a straight forward way.

```
def write_to_file(data):
    with open('./credentials.json', "w") as fp:
        json.dump(json.loads(data), fp
        )

def script_starter():
    data1 = json.dumps(data_payload, default=str)
    create_access_key(data1)

script_starter()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def create_access_key(data):
    with open('./credentials.json', "w") as fp:
        json.dump(data, fp
        )

def script_starter():
    data["AccessKey"]["CreateDate"] = data["AccessKey"]["CreateDate"].strftime("%x")
    create_access_key(data)

script_starter()
```