# Get max and min formatted date values from queryset in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a one to many relation between `session` and `camp`. Now I have to get the max and min dates of all camps combined for a particular `session`.

I am able to do it like this:

```
sess = Session.objects.last()
max_min_dates = sess.camp.aggregate(Min('start_date'), Max('end_date'))
```

But if I try to send this from `HttpResponse` then I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable
```

So I need to send the formatted date values in that. How can I modify the above code to get the same?

Comment: Some useful info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable
Otherwise, show more of your code so we can see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The default encoder for json.dumps() does not support date encoding (ie. can't convert date into str). You can use django encoder instead, it supports a few more data types see the link for more info.

[Django Ref](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder)

```
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

json_str = json.dumps(max_min_dates, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```