# Serializing (to json) a dictionary containing a Django queryset which contains DecimalField items

Tags: python, json, django, serialization

I have a Django queryset containing model objects with some fields being Decimal objects, a format that doesn't exist in json. I know how to use Django serializers to convert this queryset to json.

However, I need to wrap the queryset in a dictionary before sending it to the front-end, like so:

```
{ "type": "stream1", "data": queryset }
```

Serializers don't work here. Error is "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'". I understand why this is the case.

What I've tried (nested json objects):

I serialized the queryset and then added it to the dictionary before converting the dictionary to json. But this is inelegant since it requires the front-end to parse the dictionary first, and then parse the serialized value inside it. Makes for a poor experience.

How do I serialize the dictionary containing the Django queryset in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't receive an answer to my question here but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11875813/10617688) (Django section) solved my problem, even though it was not in the context of Decimal objects, but datetime objects.

DjangoJSONEncoder ftw.