# Why is datetime.strptime outputting dates as serialized?

Tags: python, json, datetime, serialization

I'm simply trying to convert a date-string to a date:

```
import datetime
exampleDate = 'Jul 8 2021'
datetime.datetime.strptime(exampleDate, '%b %d %Y')
```

However, I'm later outputting this to a json, and i'm getting an error:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 8, 0, 0) is not JSON serializable
```

Can confirm in Python console that exampleDate is not printing out as a date, but rather in this serialized fashion.  All I want is: `2021-07-08`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Comment: I tried to read this info - converting to str() did not work for me..

Comment: Converting to string definitely works.  You must have made a mistake.  Show us the code and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you cannot put `datetime.datetime` to JSON.
You will need to format that to a string.

```
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(exampleDate, '%b %d %Y')
```

`type(d)` is `datetime.datetime`

Now let's convert that to a string with `strftime`:

```
date_str = d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
print(date_str)
```

You get the format you expected: `2021-07-08`. Then you put this to JSON.

Comment: really appreciate it!  what does strftime do that strptime doesnt?

Comment: `strftime` formats datetime to string with specified format; `strptime` parses a string of specified format to a datetime object.