# ndarray is not JSON serializable TypeError on working script (Tableau Prep - TabPy)

Tags: python, json, tornado, tabpy

I have working code using test data, seen here:
(sample data matches type and format of inputs that I will be using this script with later, including dates as strings appended with 'Z')

```
    from sklearn import linear_model
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
     
     
    d = {'Start Sunday of FW': ['2022-03-02Z', '2022-03-03Z', '2022-03-04Z', '2022-03-05Z', '2022-03-06Z', '2022-03-01Z',
                  '2022-03-02Z', '2022-03-03Z', '2022-03-04Z', '2022-03-05Z', '2022-03-06Z', '2022-03-01Z'],
         'Store': [1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 1111, 2222, 2222, 2222, 2222, 2222, 2222],
         'Sales': [3163, 4298, 2498, 4356, 4056, 3931, 3163, 4298, 2498, 4356, 4056, 1]}
     
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
     
    def get_coef(input):
         def model1(df):
              y = df[['Sales']].values
              x = df[['Start Sunday of FW']].values
              return np.squeeze(linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x,y).coef_)
     
         cnames = {'Store': 'Store', 0: 'Coef'}
     
         def prep_input(df):
              df['Start Sunday of FW'] = df['Start Sunday of FW'].astype('string').str.rstrip('Z').astype('datetime64[ns]')
              return df
     
         return pd.DataFrame(prep_input(input).groupby('Store').apply(model1)).reset_index().rename(columns=cnames)
     
    print(get_coef(df))
```

This code runs fine on its own.

I have installed [Tableau Prep and TabPy, and set it up correctly per instructions.](https://help.tableau.com/current/prep/en-us/prep_scripts_TabPy.htm)

When I try to run the version in the code block **below** from Prep, however, the Prep flow fails and I get the error:

````
```2022-04-06,13:08:58 [ERROR] (base_handler.py:base_handler:115): Responding with status=500, message="Error processing script", info="TypeError : Object of type ndarray is not JSON serializable"```
````

If I instead have it `print()` the current `return` line from `get_coef()`, return the `input` instead, and remove the `get_output_schema` function: the return is printed correctly, the output does flow to Tableau Prep in the live previews, **but** the error still raises and the flow still won't work, which is baffling.

```
    from sklearn import linear_model
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
     
    def get_coef(input):
         def model1(df):
              y = df[['Sales']].values
              x = df[['Start Sunday of FW']].values
              return np.squeeze(linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(x,y).coef_)
     
         cnames = {'Store': 'Store', 0: 'Coef'}
     
         def prep_input(df):
              df['Start Sunday of FW'] = df['Start Sunday of FW'].astype('string').str.rstrip('Z').astype('datetime64[ns]')
              return df
     
         return pd.DataFrame(prep_input(input).groupby('Store').apply(model1)).reset_index().rename(columns=cnames)
     
    def get_output_schema():
         return pd.DataFrame({
              'Store' : prep_string(),
              'Coef' : prep_decimal()
         })
```

Can someone help me understand the issue? I don't know anything about JSON serialization to begin with, so posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable?rq=1) are of little help to me; I can't even assess relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = pd.DataFrame(prep_input(input).groupby('Store').apply(model1)).reset_index().rename(columns=cnames)
     result['Coef'] = result['Coef'].astype('double')

     return result
```

Coef was dtype object, TabPy requires double.