# JSON Dictionary in .txt value has None type as a value, can't import correctly?

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary, plaid

working on a larger project utilizing an API and I am having issues writing / reading the JSON response as a dictionary in a .txt file. I believe I have gotten to the point where the error seems to be driven by the formatting of the dictionary, which writes values in the dictionary such as `None` and `datetime.date(2020, 7, 11)`.

What am I doing in writing or reading this incorrectly?

I read in by:

```
with open('./testing/txns.txt', 'r') as f:
    txns = f.read()
txns = txns.replace("'", "\"") # to solve for single quotes
```

Sample of what might be in 'txns.txt':

```
               {'account_owner': None,
               'amount': 6.33,
               'authorized_date': datetime.date(2020, 12, 23)}
```

Error from reading:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 19 (char 18)
```

If you need more context - I am happy to provide that. I am trying to work with Plaid's API, specifically the Transactions endpoint and `client.transactions_get(request)`. I successfully acquired transactions through this line, and I would now like to debug, do discovery, and develop with this sample data. I cannot write it and read it correctly and I *think* this is why :)

**Update1:**
This is my code now

```
response = client.transactions_get(request)
with open('txns.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(response.to_dict()))
```

Error:`TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable`

**Update2 - SOLVED**
With the help of Alex & [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable) I figured it out:

f.write(json.dumps(response.to_dict(), default=str))

Comment: That simply is not JSON - the `datetime.date()` is an even more serious violation of the spec than `None`.

Comment: If it weren't for the `datetime.date()` call you could use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the quick response. I figured it was something with that. Looks like this might be something I need to target some help from the Plaid API side. When I print(type(object_i_want_to_write))it says List, but I can't get this to write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the commenters are correct that the Plaid Python client library doesn't return this value as JSON. There's a section about this in the README at https://github.com/plaid/plaid-python#converting-the-response-to-a-json

> Converting the response to a JSON
>
> As this is a common question, we've
> included this in the README. plaid-python uses models like
> `TransactionsGetResponse` to encapsulate API responses. If you want to
> convert this to a JSON, do something like this:
>
> ```
>   import json 
>   ... 
>   response = ... # type TransactionsGetResponse
>   # to_dict makes it first a python dictionary, and then we turn it into a 
>   # string JSON. 
>   json_string = json.dumps(response.to_dict())
> ```

Comment: Alex thank you for the quick response! This is still returning an error when I try to write to a file. Is it because of something I'm doing with the file write itself, or am I not converting to json string correctly? See update in original post!

Comment: Added update above with error message. Thanks for helping!

Comment: SOLVED with help of Alex & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable...