# pyjq throws error Cannot iterate over string ("[\n {\n...)

Tags: jq, amazon-iam, python-3.7

I am trying to filter output of boto3 iam list_roles method. So i would like to get roles which have Pricipal as AWS mentioned in AssumeRolePolicyDocument. I would like to omit all roles which have Principal as service in AssumeRolePolicyDocument. This working for jq but not with pyjq

```
import pyjq
import boto3
import re
import json

client = boto3.client("iam")
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_roles')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate()
for page in response_iterator:
    role_list = json.dumps(page['Roles'], indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    my_data = pyjq.all(".[].AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS",role_list)
    print(my_data)
```

But this is throwing error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iam.py", line 16, in <module>
    my_data = pyjq.all(".[].AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS",role_list)
  File "/home/ssm-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyjq.py", line 50, in all
    return compile(script, vars, library_paths).all(_get_value(value, url, opener))
  File "_pyjq.pyx", line 211, in _pyjq.Script.all
_pyjq.ScriptRuntimeError: Cannot iterate over string ("[\n    {\n...)
```

Appreciate any suggestions on how to fix above issue?

Comment: Your error message and code do not match. (`.Statement[].Principal.AWS` is missing from the error message). I have never used `pyjq` myself, but can it handle strings or do you have to call it with a JSON object (not the serialized string)? Because the error message sounds like you are trying to iterate over a string, not an array. Or perhaps `Statement` is a serialized JSON array and not a real JSON array? Without seing the content of `role_list` nobody will be able to help. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and then [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Also note that there's a stray `roles_list=[]` variables that's never used (and `roles_list` != `role_list`)

Comment: Your input should be the object itself, not in its serialized form. Just pass in `page['Roles']` in directly.

Comment: Already tried with page['Roles'], but as there are some datatime objects in page['Roles'] it is throwing  "TypeError: <class 'datetime.datetime'> could not be converted to json" error

Answer (score 0):

Use `default=json_serial` (instead of `default=str`) as per [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Other solutions are also given there. https://github.com/ijl/orjson looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

below will give you expected answer, use `select` query from jq to filter.

This will give you list of iam roles with principal as "AWS"

```
import pyjq
import boto3
import re
import json

iam_client = boto3.client("iam")
paginator = iam_client.get_paginator('list_roles')
response_iterator = paginator.paginate()
my_data = []
for page in response_iterator:
    role_list = json.dumps(page['Roles'], indent=4, sort_keys=True, default=str)
    role_list_new = json.loads(role_list) #//convert back to json for use in pyjq    
    my_data2 = pyjq.all('map(select(.AssumeRolePolicyDocument.Statement[].Principal.AWS != null ) )',role_list_new)    
    role_dict = {}
    for my_list in my_data2:
        for role in my_list:
            print(role['RoleName'])
            print(role['AssumeRolePolicyDocument'])
            print("\n")
            acc_nums = re.findall('\d{12}', str(role['AssumeRolePolicyDocument']['Statement']) )
            new_acc_num_list = list(set(acc_nums))
            role_dict['RoleName'] = role['RoleName']
            role_dict['account_mentioned']=new_acc_num_list
            my_data.append(role_dict)
            
print(my_data)
```