# Python program is not writing to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, file

I have a Python program that needs to add an object to a JSON file. When I send the string over, it's not writing to the file, but it gives a "object of date time is not serializable". Here's my code:

```
subreddit_timestamp = {str(subreddit.display_name) : {"time_last_received" : current_time}}

    with open("last_seen.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(subreddit_timestamp))
```

I tried changing the formatting of the *subreddit_timestamp* variable, thinking it was a formatting issue, but that didn't work. I also tried putting preexisting objects into the JSON file to see if that was an issue, and it wasn't.

Comment: Whats the format of current_time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to overcome "datetime.datetime not JSON serializable"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875770/how-to-overcome-datetime-datetime-not-json-serializable)

Comment: Quick answer is `json.dump(subreddit_timestamp, file, default=str)`

Comment: The code, as posted, doesn't look like being syntactically correct. Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message implies, you couldn't serialize datetime object.
Instead you can format it into a string representation.

```
# Assuming `current_time` is a datetime object
current_time_str = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
subreddit_timestamp = {str(subreddit.display_name) : {"time_last_received" : current_time_str}}

with open("last_seen.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(subreddit_timestamp))
```