# JSON looking string (or "\" in output) of Flask Restful/Pymongo JSON output

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

First, reference links to other questions I read through.  They might be clues to what I am experiencing, although I am not understanding enough yet to see the solution to my problem.

[How can I use Python to transform MongoDB's bsondump into JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867538/how-can-i-use-python-to-transform-mongodbs-bsondump-into-json)

[Unable to deserialize PyMongo ObjectId from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409194/unable-to-deserialize-pymongo-objectid-from-json)

I've got a Flask Restful API I'm working on.  An excerpt of my code is as follows:

```
class DeviceAPI(Resource):

    def get(self, deviceID):
        # do the query
        deviceCollection = db['device']
        device = deviceCollection.find_one({'deviceID': deviceID})

        print device   #1
        print ''

        print json_util.dumps(device)   #2
        print ''

        s = json_util.dumps(device)
        print s  #3
        print ''

        results = {}
        results['device'] = s 

        print results  #4

        # respond
        return results #5
```

At Print #1, I get the following, and I understand and expect this.

```
{u'deviceID': u'ABC123', u'_id': ObjectId('....')}
```

At Print #2 and #3 are identical outputs as expected, and again I understand and expect this (I think).

```
{"deviceID": "ABC123", "_id": {"$oid": "...."}}
```

Print #4 has an added key in the dictionary.  However, it looks like the value of the key:value is a string where it should be the dictionary as in #2 and #3.

```
{'device': '{"deviceID": "ABC123", "_id": {"$oid": "...."}}'}
```

The returned result, #5, according to CURL is along the lines of the following.  There are the added / in the there.  I suspect because of #4 value looking like a string and that continues in #5 as well.

```
{"device": "{\"deviceID\": \"ABC123\", \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"....\"}}"}
```

I'm trying to get a pure JSON output, not a string representation of the device document.  #2 and #3 looked like JSON, but in #4 became a string.  Why?  And how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because `json_utils.dumps` is converting your `device` variable into a string when you should be just returning a complete json object. You essentially end up returning something that resembles this:

```
return {"device": "a string that resembles json"}
```

Instead, modify your code to look like this:

```
class DeviceAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, deviceID):
        # do the query
        deviceCollection = db['device']
        device = deviceCollection.find_one({'deviceID': deviceID})

        results = {'device': device}
        return results
```

Now, we're returning json that looks more like this:

```
return {"device": {"deviceID": "ABC123", "_id": {"$oid": "...."}}}
```

However, it looks like the recommended way to return json in flask is to actually use the [flask.jsonify](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.json.jsonify) method so that Flask will return a proper response object:

```
from flask import jsonify

class DeviceAPI(Resource):
    def get(self, deviceID):
        # do the query
        deviceCollection = db['device']
        device = deviceCollection.find_one({'deviceID': deviceID})

        return jsonify(device=device)
```

Comment: Thank you for looking at this Michael0x2a.  I agree with the concise analysis on what is being returned, but the proposed solutions aren't working, there is a "TypeError: ObjectId('....') is not JSON serializable" error.

Comment: The reason for the `dumps` from the BSON json util is so that internal objects such as `ObjectId` and `Date` BSON types are serialized to a standard JSON form. It's very mongoDB specific and not just a base python case. Hence the problem with using other json encoders.

Answer (score 1):

Michael0x2a helped to clear some fog in my mind, and after more experimenting and thinking this through, the following is working for me.

```
results['device'] = json.loads(json_util.dumps(device))
```

In my experimenting I was using json_util.dumps and json_util.loads.  But I didn't recognize that while json_util.dumps was converting the BSON like item to JSON string, that json_util.loads was converting it directly back.  Therefore, another function was needed to take the string like JSON output of json_util.dumps and make it into a dictionary JSON like object.  Thus a combo was needed.  This is using "import json" and "from bson import json_util" (of Pymongo).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply
I had the same problem as you, and it was fixed just because you post back the solution, thanks million! Follow below my code

```
from flask_restplus import Namespace, Resource, fields
from .. import mongo

import json
from bson import json_util

api = Namespace('inventory', description='Store management related operations')

@api.route('/items')
class Inventory(Resource):
    def get(self):
        inventory_collection = mongo.db.inventory
        resp = inventory_collection.find({})
        a = json.loads(json_util.dumps(resp))
        return {'result': a }
```