# How to read json file containing ObjectId and ISODate in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pymongo

I want to read a JSON file that contains ObjectId and ISODate.

JSON DATA :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5baca841d25ce14b7d3d017c"),
    "country" : "in",
    "state" : "",
    "date" : ISODate("1902-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: First off, we need a little more information. What have you tried? Do you have any code to show us? Please consider a [mcve]. Also, as @MikeScotty pointed out, that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Please format your code. More info on this here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: @artomason i got that file from mongodb,  but need to process it

Comment: Unfortunately, the JSON library included with Python needs your JSON to actually be valid to work. You can check out https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file should help you get started. You can use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate your JSON data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file)

Answer (score 6):

I want to expand a little on [Maviles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2653486/maviles)' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889647/2377454) by adding a couple of notes from a couple of other SO questions.

First, from «[Unable to deserialize PyMongo ObjectId from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409194/2377454)» we learn that this data looks like the Python representation of an actual BSON/MOngo Extended JSON object. Native BSON files are also binaries, not text.

Second, from «[How can I use Python to transform MongoDB's bsondump into JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11867538/2377454)» we can expand on [Fabian Fagerholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413118/fabian-fagerholm)'s answer:

```py
def read_mongoextjson_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        # read the entire input; in a real application,
        # you would want to read a chunk at a time
        bsondata = '['+f.read()+']'

        # convert the TenGen JSON to Strict JSON
        # here, I just convert the ObjectId and Date structures,
        # but it's easy to extend to cover all structures listed at
        # http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON
        jsondata = re.sub(r'ObjectId\s*\(\s*\"(\S+)\"\s*\)',
                          r'{"$oid": "\1"}',
                          bsondata)
        jsondata = re.sub(r'ISODate\s*\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)',
                          r'{"$date": \1}',
                          jsondata)
        jsondata = re.sub(r'NumberInt\s*\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)',
                          r'{"$numberInt": "\1"}',
                          jsondata)

        # now we can parse this as JSON, and use MongoDB's object_hook
        # function to get rich Python data structures inside a dictionary
        data = json.loads(jsondata, object_hook=json_util.object_hook)

        return data
```

As you see comparing the previous version and this one it is quite simple to handle the types. Use [MongoDB Extended JSON reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) for any other you need.

A couple of additional caveats:

- the file I was working on was a series of objects, but it wasn't a list, I have worked around by putting everything in square brackets:

```py
   bsondata = '['+f.read()+']'
```

Otherwise I would get a `JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 38 column 2 (char 1016)` at the end of the first object.

- in the first attempts, I had an issue with `json_utils` from `bson`, this thread «[importing json_utils issues ImportError](https://github.com/py-bson/bson/issues/19)» helped me, i. e.:

```
pip uninstall bson
pip uninstall pymongo
pip install pymongo
```

Here's a [paste](https://pastebin.com/UqYhp2cw) with a complete working example.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem, and the bson package would only help if you already had the data on a dict type.

If you have it already in a dict, you can convert it to a json like this ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409194/unable-to-deserialize-pymongo-objectid-from-json)):

```
from bson import json_util
import json

resulting_json = json.dumps(your_dict, default=json_util.default)
```

If you have it as a string, bson will not help. So I just removed the objects and made a strict json string and converted to a dict:

```
import json
import re

#This will outputs a iterator that converts each file line into a dict.
def readBsonFile(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as data_in:
        for line in data_in:
            # convert the TenGen JSON to Strict JSON
            jsondata = re.sub(r'\:\s*\S+\s*\(\s*(\S+)\s*\)',
                              r':\1',
                              line)

            # parse as JSON
            line_out = json.loads(jsondata)

            yield line_out
```

A file with this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5baca841d25ce14b7d3d017c"), "country" : "in", "state" : "", "date" : ISODate("1902-01-31T00:00:00.000Z")}
```

will output this dict:

```
     {  "_id" : "5baca841d25ce14b7d3d017c",
        "country" : "in",
        "state" : "",
        "date" : "1902-01-31T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called "BSON" format and you can install `bsondump` from MongoDB and use that app to convert the file into "Extended JSON" format, which can be parsed by JSON libraries.

```
bsondump < input.bson > output.json
```